# Image viewer with mousewheel scrolling

Tags: software-recommendation, eog, gthumb

Is there an image viewer which allows the user to **scroll** the zoomed image using the mouse wheel?

It's a crucial functionality, which I'm missing in EOG, gThumb etc...

Comment: Uri: yes it does. What I am looking for is scrolling.

Comment: Nice. However, I need to be able to move around using two-finger scrolling (which is ~ mousewheel).

Comment: In gimp you can click on the magnifier (or hit Z) then press Ctrl and scroll to zoom.

Comment: In gThumb, you can zoom by holding CTRL and scrolling the mouse wheel. Works in gThumb 3.8.0.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it seems difficult to configure most image viewing software like `gthumb`, `shotwell`, or `eog` to do this. There doesn't seem to be any hidden options available in `dconf-editor` or `gsettings` after investigation.

There are two possibilities, however:

1. The first is `Pinta`, which is available in the repositories and supports scrolling a zoomed image well. It supports using the mouse scroll wheel to scroll vertically, and you can also click to scroll horizontally.

   [image]
2. The second is to use `firefox` in conjunction with the [image zoom 0.4.6](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/image-zoom/) addon, and then you can zoom into the picture and indeed scroll it. Firefox supports most image formats, and you can just right click and open an image in Firefox or open it like this:

   `firefox /home/mike/Pictures/IMG_1207.JPG`

   which will then be displayed in the browser at the local address of

   `file:///home/mike/Pictures/IMG_1207.JPG`

   `Firefox` can be used like a file manager for local or network files and most images formats like `jpg`, `tif`, `gif`, `png` can be opened.

   As you can see in the screenshot below, there are settings for the scroll zoom when you go to firefox > addons > image zoom > preferences. Scrolling using both the middle mouse wheel or the two fingers mode on the touchpad works as well.

   As noted in the [description](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/image-zoom/) for the addon, you can use it to:

   > easily zoom in, zoom out, fit image to screen or set custom zoom on individual images...All this can be done by using the context menu or a combination of mouse buttons and scroll wheel.

   Just open the image in `firefox`, zoom it up and then you are able to scroll it; it is about the best way of achieving what you want at the minute and I use it regularly.

   [image]

Comment: +1 Nice! This might work nice for 1 picture. However, I am usually browsing many of them (reading a scanned book, with 2 pages per 1 image). I'll let this open in case someone finds an EOG-like viewer with mousewheel scrolling.

Answer (score 3):

### Eye of Gnome, `eog`

#### In 16.04 LTS

There are scrolling functions in `eog`. This is how it works in my 16.04 LTS with eog version 3.18.2-1ubuntu2.1

When the cursor is

- in the picture itself, the scroll wheel zooms in and out,
- on the vertical scrollbar, the scroll wheel scrolls upwards and downwards,
- on the horizontal scrollbar, the scroll wheel scrolls to the left and to the right.

Two finger scrolling works in the same way (I tested in my laptop).

---

I prefer to press the left mouse button in the picture itself and move it, which makes the picture move with the cursor. This works not only with the mouse but also with a touchpad: press the left button and move a finger to make the picture move with the finger alias *pan* the picture.

---

#### In Bionic Beaver (to become 18.04 LTS)

I tested `eog` version 3.28.0-2 in Bionic Beaver Beta-2 in a Dell Latitude E7240 with a **touch screen**.

The mouse and touchpad work as in the older versions, but there is also new functionality, when you use the touch screen. You can zoom with two fingers (by moving the fingers from each other), and you can move one finger (or two fingers) to make the picture move with the finger(s) alias *pan* the picture.

It works like in a smartphone.

The working mode can change so that moving one finger can zoom and also flip the picture (rotate by 90 degrees). I have not tested enough (in the Dell Latitude E7240) to learn what makes the working mode change.

[Ubuntu Development version / How to participate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate)

Comment: +1 because I was about to post `eog` myself :) I'm not sure about the last paragraph because I can still use mouse scroll wheel to zoom in/out **and** use left click to pan the image. The last paragraph makes it sound like they are somehow mutually exclusive.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, thanks for your comment :-) I have tried to improve that part of the answer.

Comment: Doesn't really help. I'd like it to scroll like in Chrome or Firefox when you have a very big image. Hovering and scrolling over scrollbar doesn't work since I cannot scroll sideways when hovering on vertical scrollbar and vice versa for horizontal scrollbar. You know, some scrollwheels support scrolling in all directions.

Comment: Maybe using Chrome or Firefox is the solution for you until there is some (other)  program, that can do what you want?

Comment: @SeppoErviälä, Have you tried the default image viewer in Kubuntu Bionic (to become 18.04 LTS)? I would prefer eog, but maybe you would prefer the Kubuntu image viewer.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a program which lets you scroll an image after clicking the mouse wheel button.

But Faststone Image Viewer lets you zoom to actual size by holding the mouse button, and while holding it you can scroll around easily with the mouse. When the button is released the image goes back to default. You can switch from actual size and default size with key commands A and B.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. This does not answer the question. When you have invested some time in the site and earned more reputation points, you will be able to comment on questions.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a very similar problem, but Chrome worked for me. I needed to work with many designs thus all of them must remain open.

1. Create a new Chrome window in case you are working with multiple images.
2. Focus this windows before doing steps below.
3. In the file explorer select all your images and right click.
4. Choose *Open with Another application*
5. Search / Choose Chrome. Sometimes you have to click on "See all applications".

After doing so, all your images will be loaded as tabs in a separate window, and the scrolling just scrolls, not zooms.

As an added benefit you can use your Chrome extensions as a color picker, just remember to give the permission to access files to the respective extensions.

I tried to use also measure plugins but I think those plugins are not aware of the use case of measuring files (in this case images) or there is some technical impossibility that impedes to work that way.

Hope that helps.