# Problem Installing 16.04.4 ISO under VMware WS Pro v14

Tags: 16.04, vmware, iso

**Use Case:**
Create a new Linux VM under VMware Workstation v14, which will be used to manually install Ubuntu from the `ubuntu-16.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso`.  (The VMware automatic option for Ubuntu exhibits the same flaw.)

---

**Problem:**
After setting the time-zone, the subsequent screen (Keyboard Layout) does not display the right-most inch of the window.

Here is the last 'normal' screen:

[image: A picture showing the 'Time Zone' selection screen from the Ubuntu graphical installation routine, within the framework of VMware Workstation 14, is displayed.]

<sup>**The Time Zone selection screen from the Ubuntu 16.04 graphical installation routine, within the framework of VMware Workstation 14**</sup>

After clicking "OK" from the image above, the installing user ends up here, the 'problem' screen:

[image: A picture showing the 'Keyboard Layout' selection screen from the Ubuntu graphical installation routine, within the framework of VMware Workstation 14 is displayed. The rightmost inch of the Ubuntu install screen, including all but the left border of the "Cancel" button and the entire "OK" button, is occluded.]

<sup>**The Keyboard layout selection screen from the Ubuntu 16.04 graphical installation routine, within the framework of VMware Workstation 14**</sup>

The above picture shows the 'Keyboard Layout' selection screen from the Ubuntu 16.04 graphical installation routine, within the framework of VMware Workstation 14.  The rightmost inch of the Ubuntu install screen contents, including all but the left border of the "Cancel" button and the entire "OK" button, is occluded.  The contents' frame is displayed correctly.

---

**Discussion:** 
After experimenting with the Tab-key, I got past this problem.  This seems to be a long-standing problem.  Leastwise the same characteristics are displayed when installing (under VMware) using the following ISO: `ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso`.

---

**Goal:**
Try to notify the developer community, so that the problem does not exist in future Ubuntu ISOs.

Comment: This is not a question, this is a bug report... should go to https://launchpad.net/

Comment: You are welcome to participate in testing and development of Ubuntu and software used together with Ubuntu. See [this link and links from it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate).