# How to add calculations to the gnome search bar?

Tags: gnome-shell, search, calculator

I was using Gnome on PureOS for a month or so, but now I'm back on Ubuntu 18.04. The thing I loved in PureOS is that I could do calculations in the Gnome search bar. But when I type any calculations (`1+2`) in the gnome search bar I see no results (it says "No results" in Dutch):

[image]

I tried [this gnome extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/111/calculator/) and it's enabled in Gnome tweak tool as you can see below, but I see no results (I rebooted to be sure).

[image]

Does anybody know how I can activate calculations in the Gnome search bar?

Comment: Looks like the extension is abandoned and incompatible with your recent GNOME Shell version. Bug reports are off topic here but you can try to [contact its author to file a bug report](https://github.com/eonpatapon/gnome-shell-extension-calc/network/members).

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked for me!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found this from [Built-in calculator to GNOME search window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062973/built-in-calculator-to-gnome-search-window)

The pre-installed GNOME Calculator in Ubuntu 18.04 is a snap application which may lack some features provided by the traditional one due to restrictions of snap packages.

Remove the snap application by running

```
snap remove gnome-calculator
```

and install the traditional apt one by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-calculator
```

You may need to to restart GNOME shell by hitting Alt+F2, then typing r and pressing Enter for it to take effect.

Comment: Had to restart, as predicted, but worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It works for me in Ubuntu 17.10 (and Wayland) with double parentheses, which is used also on the command line

```
$ echo "$((1+2))"
3
```

So try

```
((1+2))
```

See this screenshot,

[image]

After an update & upgrade it works without parentheses and with single parentheses too,

```
1+2
(1+2)
```

---

Please notice that AskUbuntu is not intended for the developing release. But you are welcome to participate in the development or testing via other web sites. See this link,

[Ubuntu Development version / How to participate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate/1018060#1018060)

Comment: Hmmm, this doesn't work either. Alright, I'll just wait until 18.04 is officially released and see whether it works then. Thanks for your effort anyway!

Comment: @kramer65, You are welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

I checked out [the github page of the extension](https://github.com/eonpatapon/gnome-shell-extension-calc) I was trying to use, which says:

> This extension is now obsolete as the gnome calculator provides this functionality since g-s 3.14

So I installed Gnome Calculator using the Software center and now it works like a charm.