# Built-in calculator to GNOME search window

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, search, activities-overview, gnome-calculator

Using Ubuntu 18.04.

On prior versions of Ubuntu GNOME, I could type basic expressions into the gnome search bar and get the answer. Ever since I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 however, I cannot; it shows no results.

[image: No results]

I've already found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018523/how-to-add-calculations-to-the-gnome-search-bar) but GNOME Calculator is already installed on my machine and still no luck. Any ideas?

The below answer used to work, but seems to no longer under Gnome 3.28.4. The best alternative I've found so far is to install [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/900/modern-calc/), but it is a poor substitute.

Answer (score 22):

The pre-installed GNOME Calculator in Ubuntu 18.04 is a [snap](https://docs.snapcraft.io/snaps/intro) application which may lack some features provided by the traditional one due to restrictions of snap packages.

Remove the snap application by running

```
snap remove gnome-calculator
```

and install the traditional apt one by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-calculator
```

You may need to to restart GNOME shell by hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then typing `r` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> for it to take effect.

---

**Update:** Version `1:3.28.2-1~ubuntu18.04.3` of the apt version of GNOME Calculator has stopped showing calculations in search results, refer to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-calculator/+bug/1859555).

Comment: This has been driving me nuts since I upgraded, thanks for this

Comment: How can I get this working on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @user507974 Ubuntu 16.04 comes with Unity *instead of* GNOME by default, so this won't apply unless you're using GNOME. Consider asking a new question.

Comment: Hmm, something appears to have broken this again on my system. I tried redoing the steps here to no avail. Will need to investigate

Comment: same here, it was working fine a month ago and since recent usystem updates it doesn't anymore.

Comment: @user16565 It's a new bug introduced in v1:3.28.2-1~ubuntu18.04.3: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-calculator/+bug/1859555

Comment: This   is   so   sad   !   :cry: