# Air mouse not working if attached directly to USB, but it works if attached using a hub

Tags: 16.04, usb, mouse

I have this strange problem with an air mouse of FREEWAY TECHNOLOGY on Ubuntu 16.04.

If I connect the USB key using an USB-hub the device works perfectly, if I try to connect it directly to a computer USB port I get some errors and the device doesn't work.

Extract of the syslog WITH USB-hub

```
Mar 29 11:42:58 platform kernel: [ 1344.911671] usb 1-1.2.3: USB disconnect, device number 27
Mar 29 11:43:03 patform kernel: [ 1349.496675] usb 1-1.2.1: new full-speed USB device number 28 using xhci_hcd
Mar 29 11:43:03 platform kernel: [ 1349.612652] usb 1-1.2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0c45, idProduct=5012
Mar 29 11:43:03 platform kernel: [ 1349.612656] usb 1-1.2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Mar 29 11:43:03 platform kernel: [ 1349.612658] usb 1-1.2.1: Product: RFIC-MOUSE
Mar 29 11:43:03 platform kernel: [ 1349.612660] usb 1-1.2.1: Manufacturer: FREEWAY TECHNOLOGY
Mar 29 11:43:03 platform kernel: [ 1349.617590] input: FREEWAY TECHNOLOGY RFIC-MOUSE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.1/1-1.2.1:1.0/0003:0C45:5012.000B/input/input21
Mar 29 11:43:03 platform kernel: [ 1349.677578] hid-generic 0003:0C45:5012.000B: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.01 Keyboard [FREEWAY TECHNOLOGY RFIC-MOUSE] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.2.1/input0
Mar 29 11:43:03 platform kernel: [ 1349.679602] input: FREEWAY TECHNOLOGY RFIC-MOUSE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.1/1-1.2.1:1.1/0003:0C45:5012.000C/input/input22
Mar 29 11:43:03 platform kernel: [ 1349.679914] hid-generic 0003:0C45:5012.000C: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.01 Mouse [FREEWAY TECHNOLOGY RFIC-MOUSE] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.2.1/input1
```

Extract of the syslog WITHOUT USB-hub

```
Mar 29 11:44:49 platform kernel: [ 1455.249788] usb 1-1.2.1: USB disconnect, device number 28
Mar 29 11:44:53 platform kernel: [ 1459.716449] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
Mar 29 11:44:53 platform kernel: [ 1459.836614] usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Mar 29 11:44:53 platform kernel: [ 1460.180018] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0c45, idProduct=5012
Mar 29 11:44:53 platform kernel: [ 1460.180022] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Mar 29 11:44:53 platform kernel: [ 1460.180024] usb 1-2: Product: RFIC-MOUSE
Mar 29 11:44:53 platform kernel: [ 1460.180027] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: FREEWAY TECHNOLOGY
Mar 29 11:44:53 platform kernel: [ 1460.185398] input: FREEWAY TECHNOLOGY RFIC-MOUSE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:0C45:5012.000D/input/input23
Mar 29 11:44:53 platform kernel: [ 1460.245606] hid-generic 0003:0C45:5012.000D: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.01 Keyboard [FREEWAY TECHNOLOGY RFIC-MOUSE] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
Mar 29 11:45:29 platform kernel: [ 1496.140349] usbhid 1-2:1.1: can't add hid device: -110
Mar 29 11:45:29 platform kernel: [ 1496.140374] usbhid: probe of 1-2:1.1 failed with error -110
Mar 29 11:45:29 platform kernel: [ 1496.140513] usb usb1-port2: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
Mar 29 11:45:29 platform kernel: [ 1496.140520] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 29
Mar 29 11:45:30 platform kernel: [ 1496.664363] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 30 using xhci_hcd
Mar 29 11:45:35 platform kernel: [ 1501.988411] usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Mar 29 11:45:51 platform kernel: [ 1517.724146] usb 1-2: new low-speed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
Mar 29 11:45:51 platform kernel: [ 1517.844190] usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Mar 29 11:45:51 platform kernel: [ 1518.072205] usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Mar 29 11:45:52 platform kernel: [ 1518.300203] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
Mar 29 11:45:57 platform kernel: [ 1523.532343] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
Mar 29 11:46:02 platform kernel: [ 1528.908189] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
Mar 29 11:46:02 platform kernel: [ 1529.116165] usb 1-2: device not accepting address 32, error -62
Mar 29 11:46:02 platform kernel: [ 1529.236316] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 33 using xhci_hcd
Mar 29 11:46:08 platform kernel: [ 1534.284170] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
Mar 29 11:46:13 platform kernel: [ 1539.660238] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
Mar 29 11:46:13 platform kernel: [ 1539.868078] usb 1-2: device not accepting address 33, error -62
Mar 29 11:46:13 platform kernel: [ 1539.868160] usb usb1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

`uname -a`

```
Linux platform 4.10.14-041014-generic #201705031501 SMP Wed May 3 19:03:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any help appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have similar experiences also with other USB devices. The devices are not quite compatible with the system in the computer (hardware and/or software), but the hub can provide an interface, that works with both the USB device and the USB system in the computer.

---

*My solution (maybe you would call it a workaround) is to use the hub and be happy.*

---

If it is a very new device, and it is a software issue, maybe a newer or future version of Ubuntu will make it work without the hub.

You can try *live*, 'Try Ubuntu', booted from a USB pendrive or DVD disk with [Ubuntu 17.10.1](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and [Ubuntu Bionic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate/1018060#1018060) to be released soon (in April 2018) as Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

The USB pendrive may or may not need the hub for the computer to boot from it ;-)

Comment: Thank you, the strange thing is that on Ubuntu 13.0 with kernel 3.11.10 the air mouse works perfectly without the hub... i'll keep investigating :)

Comment: Then it is a software issue, and unfortunately your 16.04 LTS lacks a good driver for the air mouse. Which linux kernel are you using? Please check with `uname -r`. If you run another version than in the `4.4 series`, I suggest that you try Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (the first point release), and you should definitely try Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (the first point release with kernel series 3.13). They might work (particularly 3.13 is close to 3.11). See [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13540865#post13540865). Scroll down to the end of the page.