# No internet after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: networking, dns, 18.04, tethering

After the upgrade I noticed that [I don't have internet access](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+question/667433#comment-4). The wired network and the wifi settings looked good, but it didn't work. After the login the system always switched itself into airplane mode.
I tethered the network via USB and Bluetooth by my mobile but they also didn't work.

Comment: [Ubuntu Development version / How to participate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate/1018060#1018060)

Comment: I agree the decision. And I understand the rule. You have to see that if you have a notebook with an upgraded ubuntu without internet, it is very hard to find the answer by your phone.
answers.launchpad.net isn't as well indexed as askubuntu.com

Comment: @sudodus Please reopen. 18.04 is out and I ran into the exact same issue!

Comment: @user5950, I cannot do it alone, but I will cast my reopen vote :-) But it may not work. -- In any case I suggest that you *ask a new question* (with similar title and text, but not exactly the same).

Comment: @user5950: follow the accepted answer that I copied from launchpad.net (andrew-woodhead666). It worked for me. If this is your problem, it will fix it.

Comment: how come such a bug is allowed into a dist version? I'm around with no web access for hours! Shame!

Comment: I reported the bug on launchpad. You can subscribe if you are involved: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1816530

Answer (score 41):

**Update 2**: the bugreport was refused because I couldn't reproduce it on the already upgraded system and couldn't provide data for the developers.

**Update 1**: I reported the bug on launchpad. You can subscribe if you are involved:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1816530

[the ORIGIN of the solution](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/665374)

if the `/etc/resolv.conf` is empty but you can ping 8.8.8.8

```
$ echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null
```

if the `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` is empty then you have to repeat the command above after every restart except you do this:

```
$ echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee -a /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head > /dev/null
```

then you have to restart the resolvconf and the networking

```
$ sudo systemctl enable resolvconf
$ sudo systemctl start resolvconf
$ sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: +1. This is helpful (although not quite according to the rules (AskUbuntu is only about released versions).

Comment: I am facing similar issue, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021888/ubuntu-18-04-beta-cannot-connect-to-wifi-internet?noredirect=1#comment1659461_1021888,
but your solution doesn't seem to work for me. Can you elaborate a bit on what this command tries to achieve?

Comment: @EftychiaThomaidou: Did you restart the network? `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`? Can you ping 8.8.8.8? What is the content of `/etc/resolv.conf`? Do your wired and wifi setting look good? Do you see them if you run `ifconfig -a`? What is in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file? What is the output of `sudo nmcli d`?

Comment: @ZoltánSüle plz find in the link some of the answers. I am able to pink 8.8.8.8 but not www.ubuntu.com. I just restarted the network, but nope. 
My interfaces file looks as

`auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto wlo1
#iface wlo1 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid <my ssid>
wpa-psk <my key>`


As i saw in another reply i added the last 4 lines in my file. But my laptop could no longer see any wifi networks, thus I commented them out.

Comment: is the nameserver set in the `/etc/resolv.conf` file? If not add `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to this file

Comment: adding the nameserver in the `/etc/resolv.conf`  and restarting by `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` did the magic! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @EftychiaThomaidou, Congratulations and thanks for sharing your solution/confirming that this method works :-)

Comment: @sudodus @EftychiaThomaidou: you have to add it to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` too. Otherwise you have to repeat the editing of the `/etc/resolv.conf` file after every reboot.

Comment: This is a workaround, but not a good solution, and will probably break your system in unpredictable ways in the future.  You should use the network configuration GUI or netplan to configure your network properly.

Comment: @JanC: that was the first thing that I did (tried to configure it by the GUI), but it didn't help. I will install a fresh 18.04 this weekend and I will compare the two systems.

Comment: Try removing the current configuration in the GUI and then re-add it (if you remove the resolvconf hack before doing so, that should get you the default configuration back).

Comment: BTW: make sure your network (router) assigns a correct nameserver with DHCP if that's how you configure it.

Comment: These instructions work, but let's not forget that this is just a DNS setting issue. These instructions direct you to setting it to google's public DNS (8.8.8.8) while you can easily set it to your own DNS, whatever that may be. In my case, I use my router's ability to act as a DNS server. So, I followed the instructions and instead of using 8.8.8.8 I just put in my private gateway address ex(192.168.1.1) to get it to work. This problem should be described as a naming resolution problem, and not necessarily an internet problem as you can browse sites via IP.

Comment: thank you! I had an 169 series IP address and had to comment. does that belong to the DHCP server?

Answer (score 11):

I agree with some other folks here that the selected answer is probably not the best way to fix the issue:

When a file has a comment at its beginning that says

```
"DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE"
```

then there is probably a very good reason to, well, ... not edit that file! ;-)

And here is why, as well as a suggestion for a better (IMHO) solution:

**a.** the file `/etc/resolv.conf`, that you modified, will be overwritten at boot time, so your modification won't 'stick'.

**b.** the ip address (127.0.0.53) that was originally in there (before you modified it) is actually the address of a DNS stub resolver. It's there! You can ping it! it's running locally on your machine. What is a stub resolver? It takes your DNS queries and looks in its cache for a resolution! If it can't find any, it will reach out to a real DNS server (and then cache the result). So, if you overwrite the address of the stub resolver, you're going to miss out on this important caching function of the stub resolver!

The problem with this new resolver method in Ubuntu 18.04 is that the 'real' DNS server address was never set. So, if the stub resolver doesn't find your requested domain in its cache, it doesn't know what DNS server to query. (Hence your domain name based internet accesses no longer working).
So all you have to do is configure the 'real' DNS server that this stub resolver must use. And you do this by editing (sudo!) `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`

Simply add something like

```
DNS=8.8.8.8
```

to that file.

Then restart the network, or rather, reboot, so you can verify that you now have a solution that is persistent across reboots.

(What I haven't figured out yet, is why DHCP doesn't properly set the correct DNS server!)

Comment: Didn't work for me...

Comment: I added "DNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 4.2.2.2" and then ran "systemctl restart systemd-resolved' and it worked.

Comment: Just use the IP address for all the sites you want to visit, then you don't need DNS, problem solved!

Comment: This worked perfectly for me and is the easiest to implement

Answer (score 7):

Accepted answer did solve my problem. However, as everyone else stated, that is only until you reboot which I do daily with my machine. Typing 5 to 6 lines in the terminal every time I start the system up isn't something I would find amusing.

After digging on the internet I found a solution to permanently solve the problem. I rebooted 3 times afterward just to be sure, internet connection is there and I don't have to do anything.

**Solution:**

Start the terminal and type:

```
$ ifconfig
```

Now you gotta figure out which is your Ethernet interface. Mine is listed as `eth1`. Next type:

```
$sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

My file only had:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Now what you need to do is to add the following lines afterwards:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Lastly, `$ sudo ifup eth1`, reboot and you're done. Don't forget to change `eth1` with the name of your Ethernet interface.

[Original answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1042186/873028)

Comment: This is the answer that did it for me. My computer abruptly disconnected from the router immediately after the update. That means I couldn't even visit the router's landing page at 192.168.0.1. I wrote a script called [estalker.sh](https://pastebin.com/C3g31H19), which watches the ability to curl google.com like a hawk. The instant I typed in `sudo ifup eno1`, estalker reported internet access and the landing page refreshed in chromium to show a working admin console.

Answer (score 5):

#### tl;dr

First, edit this file

```
sudo vim /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
```

Second, Add the following

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

After that, restart Ubuntu, should have internet now.

---

#### Explain

Some of the solution listed worked, but will failed once restart Ubuntu (in my case, VM),

The above solution is a tl;dr form this solution (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128223/243480) and it worked perfectly

Comment: why does this file have '/base'? The file seems located as /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d

Comment: For my ubuntu, it does have /base, and resolv.conf.d is a directory

Comment: It works for me!

Comment: Yes, just as you said: /etc/resolv.conf will be wiped after reboot. Yours is the solution I used, except I used nano ;-)

Comment: nano will be fine for this job :)

Comment: Worked for me !

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue on ubuntu 18.04 and the above answer didn't work for me as I didn't have a folder named `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/`. So I did the following

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d
sudo touch /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
```

Then I added `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to the file `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`

Then a simple network restart solved the issue.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Answer (score 1):

On the non-working updated PC the symlink was :

```
/etc/resolv.conf -> /run/resolveconf/resolv.conf
```

On a working PC with 18.04 the symlink was :

```
/etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

then I replace the old linked file with a new one :

```
rm  /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s  /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf  /etc/resolv.conf
```

(work after procedures described below)

Answer (score 0):

Changing `/etc/resolv.conf` is not the best answer to this problem. According to Ubuntu 16.04 documentation `resolv.conf` file can be overwritten by system at any time.
If you are using static IP configuration you should add one line to you `/etc/network/interfaces` file in you ethernet card configuration. It should look something like:

```
iface eth0 inet static 
    address 192.168.3.3 
    emsp;netmask 255.255.255.0 
    gateway 192.168.3.1 
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

And then to restart your network run:

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

If you want to avoid any possible problems in the future, you can do one more thing. Upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 does not change network configuration method from `/etc/network` to new `/etc/netplan` used in 18.04. If you want to change it manually look at [How to enable netplan on ubuntu server upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034711/how-to-enable-netplan-on-ubuntu-server-upgraded-from-16-04-to-18-04)

Comment: if other people confirm this is the right answer, I will accept it! Consider that my answer comes from the official ubuntu page (launchpad) and the main problem is the missing name server IP setting.
Fixing the internet is important if you want to install anything like `netplan.io`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello All Almost total noob here but I ran into this problem when I started dual booting between Windows 10 and loaded Ubuntu 18.04 on a separate hard drive. My internet wouldn't connect and my router wouldn't allow me to open up the configuration interface. I finally figured out that it was because I had DCHP set to assign a static IP to Windows 10. After checking all the information I could find and nothing working I loaded Windows 10 and removed the routers static IP from the DHCP settings. That got internet working but I wanted a static IP for Windows and Ubuntu. Best I can figure is that Ubuntu doesn't take the hand off from the routers DHCP server properly despite being set to automatic. Once I manually configured the static IP address and Gateway in Ubuntu could I go back to having aforesaid static IP.  Hope this helps someone.
Drew

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i have tried many answers, unfortunately, all can not work in my computer.
Here is my solution.
I think no internet after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04, this problem is most likely caused by the loss of the network driver. What you need to do is to reinstall it.
Visit this link [intel network driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/zh-cn/download/15817?_ga=1.159975677.114505945.1484457019), and download the driver.
The version I am using is `e1000e-3.8.4`， i haven't tried whether other version can work.
After downloading, extract this file to a folder. Enable root privileges：

```shell
sudo -i
```

Then, enter the `src` directory.

```shell
cd e1000e-3.8.4/src/
```

Note that you should change the version if you use a different driver.
Compile the driver module.

```shell
make install
```

If this step is successful, it is good. But here i meet a problem.

```shell
 error: redefinition of ‘skb_frag_off’
```

To solve this problem, you can open this file: `src/kcompat.h`. In this file, there is a function, `skb_frag_off`, comment it. And then type `make install` again, this should work.
Finally, enter

```shell
modinfo e1000e
modprobe e1000e [parameter=port1_value,port2_value]
```

At this point, you should be able to connect to the network normally.

Answer (score -1):

I solved a connection failure after an upgrade by using a wireless connection using a USB-attached network adapter, then changing to the preferred wired connection directly to the router.