# No internet after upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04

Tags: networking, upgrade, 18.04

After upgrading from 17.10 to 18.04 today, I have no internet connectivity, either wired, or wireless. Output from ip link suggests interfaces are all up, though they do have strange names. I tried the solution at https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/665374 but it didnt work for me. Suggestions as to how to debug this would help! Unfortunately, as I have no internet, it's hard to post evidence...

Answer (score 0):

Same issue faced...following worked for me:

```
identify what is your ethernet interface with command $ifconfig
```

in my case that is: enp2s0
Then add following lines in /etc/network/interfaces

```
$sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet dhcp
```

In my file last two lines were not there....once I enter those lines and given command

```
$ sudo ifup enp2s0
```

After that I inserted my LAN cable and it started working fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that but with no success. The network manager icon still says "Wired unmanaged" and clicking "connect" has no effect. I tried plugging the same cable into a different laptop and it works fine. I tried using wifi and that works fine too.  I think the problem is with network manager.