# Wifi disconnects frequently Ubuntu 18.04 (journalctl NetworkManger error codes)

Tags: 18.04, wireless, gnome, network-manager

There are obviously a number of similar questions here, e.g.:

- [Wifi Frequently Disconnecting (timeout)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032703/wifi-frequently-disconnecting-timeout)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525272/ubuntu-18-04-keep-disconnecting-from-home-wifi-virgin-media-but-keep-well-at
- [WiFi randomly disconnected on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030653/wifi-randomly-disconnected-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

and a plethora of suggested solutions. I tried a number of these fixes but they didn't work. So I thought I'd try and understand the problem more. Running `sudo journalctl -fu NetworkManager` will give me the message

```
Aug 21 17:48:41 timhome NetworkManager[864]: <warn>  [1598003321.0959] sup-iface[0x560c59b0b0b0,wlp1s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
```

whenever the wifi disconnects. In particular, I'm interested in the meaning of `(reason -4)`. I just couldn't find any reference for these codes. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I have the same issue! `sup-iface` suggests that the problem has something to do with wpa_supplicant. That's all I've found so far.

Comment: It may have to do with this issue: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203709

Comment: Following a comment on [kernel.org](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203709), I was able to eliminate this problem by [disabling IPv6 via grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309461/how-to-disable-ipv6-permanently/337736#337736). (Disabling IPv6 via NetworkManager didn't actually disable it.) I have no idea why this helped, but my wifi works much better now.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/networkmanager-list/2011-February/msg00042.html) post, you can find the reason codes [here](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/include/NetworkManager.h?id=2dbaab2221c092e1cb1855b14419964b4b8a04fc#n235). According to [this](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/networkmanager-list/2011-February/msg00047.html) you look up the code by going through the list in order. I suppose reason -4 means the 4th reason from the bottom, which corresponds to:

```
    /* Device disconnected by user or client */
    NM_DEVICE_STATE_REASON_USER_REQUESTED,
```

This suggests it is my computer which is disconnecting from the router, rather than say due to signal loss.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the negative error codes mean the error isn't on that list at all and that NetworkManager is propagating the error code from another subsystem (in this case from iwlwifi or wpa_supplicant). That list may help if it was a positive error code.