# Wireless loses Internet

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I'm new on Ubuntu and I'm having problems with the Internet connection. I came from Windows and I'm pretty lost.

I'm using a HP pavilion G6.

When I start Internet connection is working properly but after some minutes it loses Internet. I restart the network manager but it still happening.

I can solve the problem restarting computer but it is really annoying.
I look for some solution on the Web but nothing that I find (and understand) works.

Can you please help me? If there's some command that I can use to give you information please tell me and I send you what you need.

---

Result of `lscpi -k`:

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company U98Z077.00 Half-size Mini PCIe Card
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
    DeviceName: Realtek Gbe Lan Connection
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
06:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
```

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -k`

Comment: Done ty for ur help

Answer (score 0):

Was your WiFi working solidly on this same hardware before switching over to Ubuntu?

I've had problems with my WiFi here as well.  I've have had great success with Ubuntu + an ethernet-over-powerline adapter (Tenda AV1000 1-Port Gigabit Powerline Adapter).

Comment: Yes it's working on my devices correct. Even in my laptop with windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling powersave for WIFI:

In: /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf set wifi.powersave = 2

I cannot take credit for this, found at [Wifi Frequently Disconnecting (timeout)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032703/wifi-frequently-disconnecting-timeout)