# Ubuntu 18.04.6 Connected to Wi-Fi but getting randomly disconnected from internet

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager, internet

I have a **Dell Core i5** laptop that has **Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS.**
I was using this laptop since last 2 years with no problem with WiFi connection but from last 2 days, it starts showing WiFi connection issues.
The network connection getting drop randomly during the use of FireFox.
I had to restart 'network-manager' to get the connection back as:

**sudo service network-manager restart**

and then it works fine for 5min or 20min or 30min and then loses connection again.
My WiFi router works fine with other devices.

I saw similar posts on the internet for Ubuntu connection problems and I tried all but no luck.
I tried disabling the IPv6 in network manager but it didn't fix the issue.
When connection drops, I can't ping following or access the web page:
ping [www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com)
pint 8.8.8.8

I will greatly appreciate any help,
Thanks for your time.
nraza

Here are some info of my machine:
Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Intel® Core™ i5-8365U CPU @ 1.60GHz × 8
Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
Model name:  Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8365U CPU @ 1.60GHz

```
>> lshw -C network
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 32
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.4.0-110-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.86.245 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:129 memory:91000000-911fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (6) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno1
       version: 30
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.4-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:131 memory:91400000-9141ffff
```

@waltinator  here is the output of this: "**sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager**" command:

```
-- Logs begin at Fri 2020-12-11 09:05:07 EST, end at Thu 2022-05-19 22:08:21 EDT. --
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.2672]       interface-parser: finished parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.2673] management mode: unmanaged
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.2681] devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0, iface: wlp2s0)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.2681] device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0, iface: wlp2s0): no ifupdown configuration found.
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.2682] devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/eno1, iface: eno1)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.2682] device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/eno1, iface: eno1): no ifupdown configuration found.
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.2682] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.2682] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo): no ifupdown configuration found.
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.2683] end _init.
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.2683] settings: loaded plugin ifupdown: (C) 2008 Canonical Ltd.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list. (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.2683] settings: loaded plugin keyfile: (c) 2007 - 2016 Red Hat, Inc.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.2684] (-986639616) ... get_connections.
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.2684] (-986639616) ... get_connections (managed=false): return empty list.
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.2853] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/wifibox (b7f8523d-1939-407a-90d9-4f95b71b7546,"wifibox")
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.2957] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Jazz-LTE-D120 (ec6479c7-da15-4890-b00e-428f321020b7,"Jazz-LTE-D120")
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3035] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/HUAWEI-aGsR (3d849a2e-3b1b-4aed-b160-1cf8ddd2f43d,"HUAWEI-aGsR")
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3040] get unmanaged devices count: 0
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3040] manager: rfkill: WiFi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3040] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3040] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3041] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'dhclient'
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3042] Loaded device plugin: NMBondDeviceFactory (internal)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3042] Loaded device plugin: NMBridgeDeviceFactory (internal)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3042] Loaded device plugin: NMDummyDeviceFactory (internal)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3042] Loaded device plugin: NMEthernetDeviceFactory (internal)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3042] Loaded device plugin: NMInfinibandDeviceFactory (internal)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3042] Loaded device plugin: NMIPTunnelDeviceFactory (internal)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3043] Loaded device plugin: NMMacsecDeviceFactory (internal)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3043] Loaded device plugin: NMMacvlanDeviceFactory (internal)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3043] Loaded device plugin: NMPppDeviceFactory (internal)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3043] Loaded device plugin: NMTunDeviceFactory (internal)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3043] Loaded device plugin: NMVethDeviceFactory (internal)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3043] Loaded device plugin: NMVlanDeviceFactory (internal)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3043] Loaded device plugin: NMVxlanDeviceFactory (internal)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3050] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3054] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3056] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3057] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3060] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3066] device (lo): carrier: link connected
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3070] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3078] manager: (eno1): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3086] keyfile: add connection in-memory (26b62a52-9036-38ab-a185-eb9b8c5c25fa,"Wired connection 1")
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3088] settings: (eno1): created default wired connection 'Wired connection 1'
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3095] device (eno1): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3101] wifi-nl80211: (wlp2s0): using nl80211 for WiFi device control
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3102] device (wlp2s0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3107] manager: (wlp2s0): new 802.11 WiFi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.3113] device (wlp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.6050] bluez: use BlueZ version 5
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.6058] modem-manager: ModemManager available
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.6128] supplicant: wpa_supplicant running
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.6128] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: init -> starting
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.6164] bluez5: NAP: added interface 8C:C8:4B:3B:E8:34
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.7371] sup-iface[0x563fc52a9a40,wlp2s0]: supports 5 scan SSIDs
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.7384] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
May 19 22:06:17 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012377.7385] device (wlp2s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.6418] policy: auto-activating connection 'wifibox'
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.6428] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'wifibox' (b7f8523d-1939-407a-90d9-4f95b71b7546)
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.6429] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.6430] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.6434] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.6436] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'wifibox' has security, but secrets are required.
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.6436] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.6462] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.6465] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.6467] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'wifibox' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.6468] Config: added 'ssid' value 'wifibox'
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.6468] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.6468] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.6468] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.6468] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.7189] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: ready -> authenticating
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.7362] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.7551] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.7648] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> completed
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.7649] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'wifibox'.
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.7651] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.7672] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.7716] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): dhclient started with pid 7879
May 19 22:06:22 james dhclient[7879]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.86.245 on wlp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0xf01ffeb)
May 19 22:06:22 james dhclient[7879]: DHCPACK of 192.168.86.245 from 192.168.86.1
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.8399] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   address 192.168.86.245
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.8400] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.8400] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   gateway 192.168.86.1
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.8401] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   lease time 86400
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.8401] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   hostname 'james'
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.8401] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   nameserver '192.168.86.1'
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.8402] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   domain name 'lan'
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.8402] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed unknown -> bound
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.8481] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.8501] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.8509] device (wlp2s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.8514] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
May 19 22:06:22 james dhclient[7879]: bound to 192.168.86.245 -- renewal in 38480 seconds.
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.9144] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.9147] policy: set 'wifibox' (wlp2s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
May 19 22:06:22 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012382.9158] device (wlp2s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
May 19 22:06:23 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012383.3109] manager: startup complete
May 19 22:06:31 james NetworkManager[7854]: <info>  [1653012391.2122] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
```

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: That shows a successful wired connection and a successful WiFi connection. Look at `ip route` and `ip address`. OR vary the `-b 0` (`-b -1`, `-b -2`, ...) until you find a log showing a failure

Comment: I use `sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*` to disable power saving and works. I use ubuntu 22.04. You can check here https://askubuntu.com/a/1353723/1155600

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak  this is existing file:  
cat default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2
```

Comment: @waltinator I never used the wired connection, just wifi. I will try the other commands as you advised, thanks