# problem in coexistence of wifi and bluetooth at a time

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, headphones

I use **Ubuntu 18.04** on a *dell inspiron 15 3537*.

wifi and Bluetooth were working very well on my ubuntu device.

However recently I bought a new JBL headphone model MS-BT and when I connect to it with Bluetooth and play music on the headphones my wifi network speed drops down to almost to 0. It is connected but the speed decreases.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=2
```

If your problem fixed then add this change permenently by

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0 ant_sel=2" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

For more [details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030653/wifi-randomly-disconnected-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts)