# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS - Bluetooth Speaker Sound Stuttering When Unused For While

Tags: 18.04, sound, bluetooth, speakers

I'm using **Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS**, and I have a speaker that works via Bluetooth. I can connect it to my laptop easily, listen to whatever I want with pure sound and no problems, but I face the problem of sound stuttering if I didn't use the speaker for a while. This occurs when:

1. The speaker is connected via Bluetooth.
2. I don't play any music/videos/etc for something like 10 minutes.
3. I want to play some music/video/etc after 10 minutes of inactivity.
4. The sound stutters and is **very** bad.
5. If I disconnect the speaker and connect it again, it works and the sound is pure again.

It's annoying to disconnect and connect my speaker like 20 times a day, and I obviously can't keep listening to music all the time just to prevent this from happening. How can I solve this so the sound is always pure?
**Note: I tested it on other devices/operating systems and it works fine so the problem isn't from the speaker.**

Comment: Is the bluetooth speaker more than 35 feet away from the bluetooth source? Is this a USB Bluetooth adapter? Is your wireless card AND router set to "bluetooth co-existance"?

Comment: No I'm the speaker is less than 5 feet away from the source. No the speaker supports Bluetooth without USB, I connect it directly to the laptop. I enabeled "Bluetooth co-existence" as mentioned here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033684/problem-in-coexistence-of-wifi-and-bluetooth-at-a-time But still have the same problem.

Comment: That link only sets the correct antenna, not Bluetooth co-existence. If you are using the rtl8723be wireless driver, it depends on a module called btcoexist, and you should be able to see if it's loaded with `lsmod | grep -i btcoexist`. There's usually also a similar setting in your router.

Comment: You could also see if it's a wireless/BT issue, by temporarily disconnecting your wi-fi connection, and connecting your laptop to your router with an ethernet cable.

Comment: Last thing to try... boot to a Ubuntu Live 19.04 DVD/USB and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Well, it's not a "bluetooth co-existance" problem because I tried LAN instead of Wifi and the problem is still there. Don't you think that there are other solutions other than Ubuntu 19.04 as it will take a very long time to download and setup on a usb?

Comment: Many improvements were made in 19.04, and who's to say if it fixes your problem or not, but without trying, you'll never know... and you're the one asking for help after trying unsuccessfully trying to resolve the problem. It should only 30 minutes to test this.

Comment: Well, I tried it,  and it took 5 hours only to download since because of my slow Internet lol. Even worse, the issue is still there. But it was worth the effort because Ubuntu 19.04 IS cool!

Comment: Sorry it took so long to download... and it doesn't fix the problem. I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: It's okay, it was a cool experience with Ubuntu 19.04 anyways. And thanks for your help.

Comment: There may be a compatibility issue with your internal BT adapter. If you can find/try a USB BT adapter, it might work better.

Comment: I don't have one currently, but I'll search for a good one and try it.

Comment: See https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B007Q45EF4/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1 for only $12. I bought one for my sister and it seems to work well.

Comment: Thanks for recommending that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

- we verified that the BT speaker was within physical range
- we tried checking for `bluetooth-coexistance` settings
- we turn off wi-fi and used ethernet lan
- we tried 19.04

Recommend trying an external USB BT adapter. This one https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007Q45EF4 is only $12, and it works fine on my sister's computer.