# wifi drop constantly after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04

Always get wifi drop after upgrade to 18.04. The connection will be loss and the wifi symbol will become a question mark later.

Already tried the solutions mentioned here:
[WiFi randomly disconnected on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030653/wifi-randomly-disconnected-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

and also tried to diable the IPv6.

None of them works.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a Realtek WiFi AC1200 USB and the internal that is a Broadcom... . Tried the power configuration and the IPv6 disabled. None worked. Finally setting an static IPv4 to the laptop works. Hope this option help someone.