# Internet keeps dropping but wifi stays connected until I try to select network again

Tags: networking, network-manager, lenovo

I am using ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo IdeaPad 330
Every so often (once in 10 minutes), I lose internet connectivity. Wifi still stays connected as indicated by the status on notification bar.New pages don't open and existing requests are delayed.

When I go to the Status area and click on wifi> select network, it magically returns. 
I donot have to reconnect, or change network.

Just going to top right corner->Wifi SSID Name-> Select Network and cancel reconnects the Internet.

I am using ubuntu 18.04

```
 Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
```

I have already tried disabling Power management on Wifi 
[WiFi randomly disconnected on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030653/wifi-randomly-disconnected-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030653/wifi-randomly-disconnected-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts

Comment: Already tried that.

Comment: *Already tried that*... If so, please [edit] and add that information to the question as well as everything else you tried already to avoid situations like this, people suggesting what you already tried.