# 5GHz WiFi keeps disconnecting on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: 18.04, wireless, network-manager, atheros

I reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on my Acer Switch Alpha 12 yesterday and now i have the problem that it keeps dropping my WiFi Signal after 1-3 minutes when i'm connected to the 5 GHz network (the 2.4GHz network works fine, but since in my case it only delivers a downstream of 10-30k vs. 160k from the 5GHz i'd highly prefer using the 5GHz Signal), the problem is very similar to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030653/wifi-randomly-disconnected-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts), but i've already tested all solutions in the comments and this time none of them worked for me, on my last Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installation on the same tablet the proposed solution from *desgua* did the trick:

> This is what stopped my wifi to get unstable, disconnecting all the
>   time, although my wifi is Centrino (not Atheros): disabling IPV6.
>
> Add the following lines to the file /etc/sysctl.conf
>
> ```
> net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
> net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
> net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
> ```
>
> Reboot.

I'm using a **Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter** with the following configuration (obtained with `sudo lshw -class network`):

> `*-network
>
>          description: Wireless interface
>          product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
>          vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
>          physical id: 0
>          bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
>          logical name: wlp1s0
>          version: 32
>          serial: 94:e9:79:54:69:0d
>          width: 64 bits
>          clock: 33MHz
>          capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
>          configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.0.0-32-generic
>   firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.0.52 latency=0
>   link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
>          resources: irq:152 memory:b1400000-b15fffff`

It is neither soft nor hard blocken (output of `rfkill list all`):

> ```
> 0: hci0: Bluetooth
>   Soft blocked: no
>   Hard blocked: no
> 1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
>   Soft blocked: no
>   Hard blocked: no
> 2: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
>   Soft blocked: no
>   Hard blocked: no
> 3: phy0: Wireless LAN
>   Soft blocked: no
>   Hard blocked: no
> ```

My router is a Unitymedia Connect Box:

> The information below shows current status of this Connect Box.
>
> Standard specification compliant      :       DOCSIS 3.0 Hardware
>
> version       :       5.01 Software
>
> version       :       CH7465LG-NCIP-6.12.18.25-2p6-NOSH Cable MAC

These are the specs of my 5GHz Signal:

> Wireless mode: 802.11a/n/ac mixed
>
> Channel (manual selected): 108
>
> Channel width: 20/40/80 MHz

I've also already tried disabling wifi power management, as proposed by *qwr*, by setting `wifi.powersafe = 2` in `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersafe-on.conf`

I've tried turning of IPV6 in the network settings, as mentioned above and as suggestet my *dzmanto* by additionally deleting line 18 in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`:

> dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers,

Other solutions i already tried are **reinstalling Gnome Network Manager** and [installing the WICD Network Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD) as supposed by *Lucas Vasconcellos Czepaniki*, which extended the period of working WiFi to 3-7 minutes, but didn't fix the problem and i reverted back to Gnome Network Manager, since removing `network-manager-gnome` and `network-manager` also removed my `gnome-control-center` and with it my settings application and by reinstalling `gnome-control-center` it automatically reinstalls `gnome-network-manager` as well.

If anybody can think of a working solution for this i'd be very grateful. I know there are several other threads about this topic, but i've been going through most of them and sadly none of their solutions worked for me.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue in Ubuntu 20.10. Sad to see there's no answer here yet.

@CaptainJack42 - Were you able to fix it?

Comment: @AnuragBhandari In the end i gave up and didn't manage to fix it, but found out that apperently there was something wrong with the network drivers and ipv6 support in Ubuntu 18.04. Back than i installed Debian 10 on the tablet which worked fine and now recently swapped to ubuntu 20.04 which also works fine now.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I guess I'll tinker with network drivers a bit.

Comment: I found this thread useful in my case https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030653/wifi-randomly-disconnected-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts, particularly answers by desgua and dzmanto. My connection hasn't dropped even once in the 10 mins since I applyed the suggestions!