# Ubuntu 19.10 Wireless Not Working after Resume

Tags: networking, network-manager, suspend, 19.10

## The problem

Wifi seems to connect fine after system bootup or reboot, but if I suspend my computer (which is a laptop, so this is happening whenever I close the laptop lid), when the computer wakes, wifi indefinitely attempts to connect and fails.

## Details

I've been trying to diagnose what's going on primarily by looking at the output of`journalctl --follow`.

Here's the bad version (where authentication seems to time out every time), which I recorded after opening my laptop from a suspended state:

```
$ journalctl --follow
-- Logs begin at Thu 2019-11-14 11:44:13 EST. --
Nov 29 10:09:56 polystichum kernel: wlp3s0: authentication with 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5 timed out
Nov 29 10:09:56 polystichum NetworkManager[9032]: <info>  [1575040196.5416] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Nov 29 10:09:56 polystichum NetworkManager[9032]: <info>  [1575040196.6415] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Nov 29 10:09:59 polystichum wpa_supplicant[9052]: wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5 (SSID='ARRIS-A0C2-5G' freq=5745 MHz)
Nov 29 10:09:59 polystichum kernel: wlp3s0: authenticate with 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5
Nov 29 10:09:59 polystichum kernel: wlp3s0: send auth to 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5 (try 1/3)
Nov 29 10:09:59 polystichum NetworkManager[9032]: <info>  [1575040199.5399] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Nov 29 10:10:00 polystichum kernel: wlp3s0: send auth to 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5 (try 2/3)
Nov 29 10:10:00 polystichum systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Nov 29 10:10:01 polystichum kernel: wlp3s0: send auth to 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5 (try 3/3)
Nov 29 10:10:02 polystichum kernel: wlp3s0: authentication with 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5 timed out
Nov 29 10:10:02 polystichum NetworkManager[9032]: <info>  [1575040202.5534] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Nov 29 10:10:03 polystichum NetworkManager[9032]: <info>  [1575040203.0548] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Nov 29 10:10:05 polystichum wpa_supplicant[9052]: wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5 (SSID='ARRIS-A0C2-5G' freq=5745 MHz)
Nov 29 10:10:05 polystichum kernel: wlp3s0: authenticate with 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5
Nov 29 10:10:05 polystichum kernel: wlp3s0: send auth to 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5 (try 1/3)
Nov 29 10:10:05 polystichum NetworkManager[9032]: <info>  [1575040205.9801] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Nov 29 10:10:06 polystichum kernel: wlp3s0: send auth to 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5 (try 2/3)
Nov 29 10:10:07 polystichum kernel: wlp3s0: send auth to 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5 (try 3/3)
Nov 29 10:10:08 polystichum kernel: wlp3s0: authentication with 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5 timed out
Nov 29 10:10:08 polystichum NetworkManager[9032]: <info>  [1575040208.5791] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Nov 29 10:10:09 polystichum NetworkManager[9032]: <info>  [1575040209.5787] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Nov 29 10:10:12 polystichum wpa_supplicant[9052]: wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5 (SSID='ARRIS-A0C2-5G' freq=5745 MHz)
Nov 29 10:10:12 polystichum kernel: wlp3s0: authenticate with 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5
Nov 29 10:10:12 polystichum kernel: wlp3s0: send auth to 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5 (try 1/3)
Nov 29 10:10:12 polystichum NetworkManager[9032]: <info>  [1575040212.5327] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Nov 29 10:10:13 polystichum kernel: wlp3s0: send auth to 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5 (try 2/3)
Nov 29 10:10:14 polystichum kernel: wlp3s0: send auth to 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5 (try 3/3)
Nov 29 10:10:15 polystichum kernel: wlp3s0: authentication with 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5 timed out
```

And here's the good version, which I recorded after rebooting my laptop with the wifi disabled and then enabling it after I'd started `journalctl --follow`:

```
$ journalctl --follow
-- Logs begin at Thu 2019-11-14 11:44:13 EST. --
Nov 29 10:20:18 polystichum gnome-software[1991]: not handling error failed for action get-category-apps: persistent network error: Get https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/search?confinement=strict%2Cclassic&fields=anon_download_url%2Carchitecture%2Cchannel%2Cdownload_sha3_384%2Csummary%2Cdescription%2Cbinary_filesize%2Cdownload_url%2Clast_updated%2Cpackage_name%2Cprices%2Cpublisher%2Cratings_average%2Crevision%2Csnap_id%2Clicense%2Cbase%2Cmedia%2Csupport_url%2Ccontact%2Ctitle%2Ccontent%2Cversion%2Corigin%2Cdeveloper_id%2Cdeveloper_name%2Cdeveloper_validation%2Cprivate%2Cconfinement%2Ccommon_ids&scope=wide&section=photo-and-video: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Nov 29 10:20:18 polystichum systemd[1]: systemd-localed.service: Succeeded.
Nov 29 10:20:18 polystichum PackageKit[1222]: resolve transaction /231_ecddddcc from uid 1000 finished with success after 421ms
Nov 29 10:20:18 polystichum gnome-software[1991]: hiding category graphics featured applications: found only 1 to show, need at least 9
Nov 29 10:20:19 polystichum PackageKit[1222]: resolve transaction /232_ebdebccd from uid 1000 finished with success after 369ms
Nov 29 10:20:19 polystichum tracker-store[1909]: OK
Nov 29 10:20:19 polystichum systemd[1412]: tracker-store.service: Succeeded.
Nov 29 10:20:19 polystichum PackageKit[1222]: resolve transaction /233_cadbceba from uid 1000 finished with success after 372ms
Nov 29 10:20:19 polystichum gnome-software[1991]: Only 8 apps for popular list, hiding
Nov 29 10:20:23 polystichum systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Succeeded.
Nov 29 10:20:36 polystichum geoclue[1219]: Service not used for 60 seconds. Shutting down..
Nov 29 10:20:36 polystichum systemd[1]: geoclue.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
Nov 29 10:20:36 polystichum systemd[1]: geoclue.service: Succeeded.
Nov 29 10:20:45 polystichum xdg-desktop-por[1586]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed
Nov 29 10:20:48 polystichum gnome-software-service.desktop[2294]: Unable to acquire bus name 'org.gnome.Software'
Nov 29 10:20:50 polystichum gnome-shell[1643]: [AppIndicatorSupport-DEBUG] Registering StatusNotifierItem :1.123/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/software_update_available
Nov 29 10:20:50 polystichum gnome-shell[1643]: [AppIndicatorSupport-FATAL] unable to update overlay icon
Nov 29 10:20:50 polystichum gnome-shell[1643]: [AppIndicatorSupport-FATAL] unable to update overlay icon
Nov 29 10:20:52 polystichum kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
Nov 29 10:20:52 polystichum kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: reporting RF_KILL (radio enabled)
Nov 29 10:20:52 polystichum systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Nov 29 10:20:52 polystichum systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Nov 29 10:20:52 polystichum kernel: usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
Nov 29 10:20:52 polystichum kernel: usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0a5c, idProduct=21e6, bcdDevice= 1.12
Nov 29 10:20:52 polystichum kernel: usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Nov 29 10:20:52 polystichum kernel: usb 1-1.4: Product: BCM20702A0
Nov 29 10:20:52 polystichum kernel: usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Broadcom Corp
Nov 29 10:20:52 polystichum kernel: usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 9C2A7081F312
Nov 29 10:20:52 polystichum mtp-probe[2342]: checking bus 1, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4"
Nov 29 10:20:52 polystichum mtp-probe[2342]: bus: 1, device: 5 was not an MTP device
Nov 29 10:20:52 polystichum kernel: Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
Nov 29 10:20:52 polystichum kernel: NET: Registered protocol family 31
Nov 29 10:20:52 polystichum kernel: Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Nov 29 10:20:52 polystichum kernel: Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Nov 29 10:20:52 polystichum kernel: Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Nov 29 10:20:52 polystichum kernel: Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Nov 29 10:20:52 polystichum kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum mtp-probe[2355]: checking bus 1, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4"
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum mtp-probe[2355]: bus: 1, device: 5 was not an MTP device
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum bluetoothd[2360]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth.
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum bluetoothd[2360]: Starting SDP server
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum dbus-daemon[941]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.577' (uid=0 pid=2360 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum bluetoothd[2360]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040853.0706] bluez: use BlueZ version 5
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x07
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum kernel: bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e6.hcd failed with error -2
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e6.hcd not found
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040853.1843] bluez5: NAP: added interface 9C:2A:70:81:F3:12
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum bluetoothd[2360]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.186 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum bluetoothd[2360]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.186 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum dbus-daemon[941]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Nov 29 10:20:53 polystichum systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Nov 29 10:20:55 polystichum gnome-software[1991]: not GsPlugin error snapd-error-quark:1: Failed to write to snapd: Operation was cancelled
Nov 29 10:20:55 polystichum gnome-software[1991]: not handling error failed for action refine: Failed to write to snapd: Operation was cancelled
Nov 29 10:20:58 polystichum systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill.service: Succeeded.
Nov 29 10:20:58 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040858.1624] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Nov 29 10:20:58 polystichum systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Nov 29 10:20:58 polystichum systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Nov 29 10:20:58 polystichum kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
Nov 29 10:20:58 polystichum kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
Nov 29 10:20:58 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040858.5702] audit: op="radio-control" arg="wireless-enabled" pid=1643 uid=1000 result="success"
Nov 29 10:20:58 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040858.5711] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi now enabled by radio killswitch
Nov 29 10:20:58 polystichum wpa_supplicant[943]: dbus: fill_dict_with_properties dbus_interface=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Interface.P2PDevice dbus_property=P2PDeviceConfig getter failed
Nov 29 10:20:58 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040858.6541] sup-iface[0x55a3e0f86920,wlp3s0]: supports 5 scan SSIDs
Nov 29 10:20:58 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040858.6548] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Nov 29 10:20:58 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040858.6548] device (wlp3s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.6506] policy: auto-activating connection 'ARRIS-A0C2-5G' (9e0beb06-0d17-4c0f-b878-2a55277edca0)
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.6527] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'ARRIS-A0C2-5G' (9e0beb06-0d17-4c0f-b878-2a55277edca0)
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.6528] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.6559] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.6565] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.6573] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'ARRIS-A0C2-5G' has security, but secrets are required.
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.6574] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.6578] sup-iface[0x55a3e0f86920,wlp3s0]: wps: type pbc start...
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.6617] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.6624] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.6629] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'ARRIS-A0C2-5G' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.6630] Config: added 'ssid' value 'ARRIS-A0C2-5G'
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.6630] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.6631] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.6631] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.6631] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.6631] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum wpa_supplicant[943]: wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5 (SSID='ARRIS-A0C2-5G' freq=5745 MHz)
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum kernel: wlp3s0: authenticate with 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum kernel: wlp3s0: send auth to 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5 (try 1/3)
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.6925] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: ready -> authenticating
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum wpa_supplicant[943]: wlp3s0: Trying to associate with 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5 (SSID='ARRIS-A0C2-5G' freq=5745 MHz)
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.6944] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum kernel: wlp3s0: authenticated
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum kernel: wlp3s0: waiting for beacon from 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum kernel: wlp3s0: associate with 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5 (try 1/3)
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum kernel: wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum wpa_supplicant[943]: wlp3s0: Associated with 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum wpa_supplicant[943]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum wpa_supplicant[943]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum kernel: wlp3s0: associated
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.8243] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum wpa_supplicant[943]: wlp3s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum wpa_supplicant[943]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.8735] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.8736] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "ARRIS-A0C2-5G"
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.8738] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.8743] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum avahi-daemon[926]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::2c9b:8eda:7342:9144.
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum avahi-daemon[926]: New relevant interface wlp3s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum avahi-daemon[926]: Registering new address record for fe80::2c9b:8eda:7342:9144 on wlp3s0.*.
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum kernel: wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 27 (30 - 3) dBm as advertised by 38:70:0c:3e:a0:c5
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.9604] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum avahi-daemon[926]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.9.
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum avahi-daemon[926]: New relevant interface wlp3s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.9666] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum avahi-daemon[926]: Registering new address record for 192.168.0.9 on wlp3s0.IPv4.
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum dbus-daemon[941]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.14' (uid=0 pid=944 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum whoopsie[1091]: [10:21:01] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum dbus-daemon[941]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.9949] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.9953] device (wlp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.9960] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.9980] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.9982] policy: set 'ARRIS-A0C2-5G' (wlp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Nov 29 10:21:01 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040861.9993] device (wlp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Nov 29 10:21:02 polystichum gsd-sharing[1804]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-user-share-webdav.service not loaded.
Nov 29 10:21:02 polystichum gsd-sharing[1804]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.service not loaded.
Nov 29 10:21:02 polystichum systemd-resolved[897]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Nov 29 10:21:02 polystichum systemd-resolved[897]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Nov 29 10:21:02 polystichum wpa_supplicant[943]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-44 noise=9999 txrate=27000
Nov 29 10:21:02 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040862.2098] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Nov 29 10:21:02 polystichum whoopsie[1091]: [10:21:02] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Nov 29 10:21:02 polystichum whoopsie[1091]: [10:21:02] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Nov 29 10:21:02 polystichum whoopsie[1091]: [10:21:02] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Nov 29 10:21:03 polystichum systemd-timesyncd[898]: Synchronized to time server for the first time 91.189.94.4:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Nov 29 10:21:04 polystichum systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill.service: Succeeded.
Nov 29 10:21:04 polystichum NetworkManager[944]: <info>  [1575040864.4291] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Nov 29 10:21:05 polystichum whoopsie[1091]: [10:21:05] online
```

As you can see, in the second example, it seems like the network connection sets up just fine. Both attempts (good & bad) are using Ubuntu 19.10's wifi set up straight out of the box. It looks like authentication times out in the bad example, but I don't know why that would be happening or how to fix it.

## Things I've Tried

I've tried restarting the network manager with `sudo systemctl restart network-manager` -- that didn't help.

I've tried setting `wifi.powersave = 2` in `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030653/wifi-randomly-disconnected-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts).

## Some system details

``````
$ screenfetch
                          ./+o+-       @polystichum
                  yyyyy- -yyyyyy+      OS: Ubuntu 19.10 eoan
               ://+//////-yyyyyyo      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.3.0-23-generic
           .++ .:/++++++/-.+sss/`      Uptime: 24m
         .:++o:  /++++++++/:--:/-      Packages: 1932
        o:+o+:++.`..```.-/oo+++++/     Shell: bash 5.0.3
       .:+o:+o/.          `+sssoo+/    Resolution: 1600x900
  .++/+:+oo+o:`             /sssooo.   DE: GNOME 
 /+++//+:`oo+o               /::--:.   WM: GNOME Shell
 \+/+o+++`o++o               ++////.   WM Theme: 
  .++.o+++oo+:`             /dddhhh.   GTK Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3]
       .+.o+oo:.          `oddhhhh+    Icon Theme: Yaru
        \+.++o+o``-````.:ohdhhhhh+     Font: Ubuntu 11
         `:o+++ `ohhhhhhhhyo++os:      CPU: Intel Core i7-3667U @ 4x 3.2GHz
           .o:`.syhhhhhhh/.oo++o`      GPU: i915drmfb
               /osyyyyyyo++ooo+++/     RAM: 2165MiB / 7643MiB
                   ````` +oo+++o\:    
                          `oo++.      

$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QS77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 4-port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 2-port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 04)
02:00.0 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller (rev 07)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 96)

$ sudo lshw 
# ... 
description: Notebook
product: 3443CTO (LENOVO_MT_3443)
vendor: LENOVO
version: ThinkPad X1 Carbon
serial: R9X52A4
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 smp vsyscall32
# ...
``````

Lastly, I should say that my previous setup was Ubuntu 16.04 (which I ran XFCE and I think some of the Xubuntu packages on top of) on this same machine, and I don't think I ever had the same problem there.