# wifi drops after ~12 hours, cannot recover except by reboot

Tags: 18.04, wireless

We have an intel NUC running ubuntu.  Using the wifi, after about ~1 day the connection drops, and when I check it cannot detect any Wifi (no SSID listed) when there are many.  Tried turning wifi off and on (via GUI, via command line) no luck.  Only "fix" currently is to reboot the entire system.  I ran a script that checked the wifi status every 5 minutes, here is the output before and after the drop:

```
Sat Dec  7 04:50:23 EST 2019
IN-USE  SSID          MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY 
*       Foghorn_Corp  Infra  161   270 Mbit/s  77      ▂▄▆_  WPA2     
wlo2      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Foghorn_Corp"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.805 GHz  Access Point: F8:E7:1E:16:CC:1C   
      Bit Rate=433.3 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=67/70  Signal level=-43 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:66679   Missed beacon:0

3: wlo2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether f4:d1:08:1f:04:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.21.1.210/24 brd 10.21.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo2
   valid_lft 2583sec preferred_lft 2583sec
inet6 fe80::660e:f044:1bee:23a0/64 scope link noprefixroute 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
############################################
############################################
Sat Dec  7 04:55:23 EST 2019
IN-USE  SSID          MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY 
*       Foghorn_Corp  Infra  161   270 Mbit/s  0       ____  WPA2     
wlo2      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off

3: wlo2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether f4:d1:08:1f:04:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.21.1.210/24 brd 10.21.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo2
   valid_lft 2283sec preferred_lft 2283sec
```

Checking dmesg there is a lot of activity at at 4:53 AM with the wifi that is probably when it went down (and nothing else around then).  Pasted at the end.

Fixes I've tried that haven't worked:

- from: [WiFi randomly disconnected on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030653/wifi-randomly-disconnected-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts))

  - set wifi.powersave = 2
  - disable ipv6

System information:

```
$ uname -r
5.0.0-37-generic

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:69:7a:07:3d:51 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlo2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:d1:08:1f:04:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:69:7a:07:3d:51 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.21.1.130/24 brd 10.21.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft 2938sec preferred_lft 2938sec
    inet6 fe80::591a:617c:bb95:2fe4/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlo2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:d1:08:1f:04:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.21.1.210/24 brd 10.21.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo2
       valid_lft 3010sec preferred_lft 3010sec
    inet6 fe80::660e:f044:1bee:23a0/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 31f0 (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3185 (rev 03)
00:0c.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 31dc (rev 03)
00:0e.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 3198 (rev 03)
00:0f.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 319a (rev 03)
00:12.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 31e3 (rev 03)
00:13.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 31d8 (rev f3)
00:13.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 31da (rev f3)
00:15.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 31a8 (rev 03)
00:1c.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 31cc (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 31e8 (rev 03)
00:1f.1 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 31d4 (rev 03)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

dmesg from time when it went down (as much as I can fit here):

```
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: Status: 0x00000100, count: 6
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: Loaded firmware version: 43.95eb4e97.0
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x00000034 | NMI_INTERRUPT_WDG           
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x0000A2F0 | trm_hw_status0
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x0048973E | branchlink2
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x0047ACCA | interruptlink1
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x000281CE | interruptlink2
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x00019C8A | data1
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x0BADCAFE | data2
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x000003FF | data3
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0xEBC03C1C | beacon time
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x67921400 | tsf low
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x00001B2D | tsf hi
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x1099537F | time gp2
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x0000002B | uCode version major
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x95EB4E97 | uCode version minor
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x00000312 | hw version
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x00C89008 | board version
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x0060019C | hcmd
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0xA6FA2000 | isr0
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x08001802 | isr2
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x40417DCC | isr3
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x0060019C | last cmd Id
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x00019C8A | wait_event
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x00000080 | l2p_control
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x00000020 | l2p_duration
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x0000003F | l2p_mhvalid
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x00000080 | l2p_addr_match
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x0000000D | lmpm_pmg_sel
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x29122002 | timestamp
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x000038E4 | flow_handler
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: Status: 0x00000100, count: 7
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x20000070 | NMI_INTERRUPT_LMAC_FATAL
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0xC008813E | umac branchlink2
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0xC0083DA8 | umac interruptlink1
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0xC0083DA8 | umac interruptlink2
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x00000800 | umac data1
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0xC0083DA8 | umac data2
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x0000002B | umac major
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x95EB4E97 | umac minor
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x10995396 | frame pointer
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0xC088627C | stack pointer
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x0060019C | last host cmd
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:32 2019] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x3, CPU2 Status: 0x23f5
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: error dump due to fw assert
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] Hardware became unavailable during restart.
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 12028 at /build/linux-hwe-FLYqTt/linux-hwe-5.0.0/net/mac80211/util.c:2065 ieee80211_reconfig+0x226/0x1250 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] Modules linked in: hid_generic usbhid ccm rfcomm bnep nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_skl snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_soc_sst_dsp ledtrig_audio snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_compress intel_rapl ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel intel_telemetry_pltdrv intel_punit_ipc intel_telemetry_core snd_hda_codec intel_pmc_ipc snd_hda_core snd_hwdep x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event i915 snd_rawmidi kvmgt vfio_mdev mdev aesni_intel arc4 vfio_iommu_type1 vfio aes_x86_64 crypto_simd snd_seq cryptd glue_helper kvm intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf snd_seq_device snd_timer btusb iwlmvm btrtl mac80211 irqbypass btbcm btintel input_leds bluetooth serio_raw iwlwifi drm_kms_helper wmi_bmof drm snd ecdh_generic i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops syscopyarea cfg80211 sysfillrect
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  sysimgblt rtsx_pci_ms soundcore mei_me memstick mei mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 rtsx_pci_sdmmc sdhci_pci r8169 ahci realtek rtsx_pci libahci psmouse cqhci sdhci i2c_hid hid wmi pinctrl_geminilake pinctrl_intel video
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] CPU: 0 PID: 12028 Comm: kworker/0:1 Not tainted 5.0.0-37-generic #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] Hardware name: Intel(R) Client Systems NUC7CJYH/NUC7JYB, BIOS JYGLKCPX.86A.0050.2019.0418.1441 04/18/2019
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] Workqueue: events_freezable ieee80211_restart_work [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] RIP: 0010:ieee80211_reconfig+0x226/0x1250 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] Code: c6 45 d6 00 c6 83 9c 04 00 00 00 48 89 df e8 11 80 fc ff 85 c0 41 89 c5 0f 84 63 01 00 00 48 c7 c7 30 07 61 c0 e8 3a 02 6d e2 <0f> 0b 48 89 df e8 a0 d3 ff ff eb b0 c6 83 9d 04 00 00 00 4c 8d a3
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] RSP: 0018:ffffa24fc1563e08 EFLAGS: 00010282
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8f17f32987a0 RCX: 0000000000000006
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] RDX: 0000000000000007 RSI: 0000000000000096 RDI: ffff8f17f7e16440
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] RBP: ffffa24fc1563e50 R08: 00000000000003ca R09: 0000000000000004
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] R10: ffffa24fc1563d18 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff8f17f3299430
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] R13: 00000000ffffff92 R14: ffff8f17f3298ff8 R15: 0ffff8f17f7e27a0
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8f17f7e00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] CR2: 00007f267cf01000 CR3: 000000019060e000 CR4: 0000000000340ef0
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] Call Trace:
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ieee80211_restart_work+0xc0/0xf0 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  process_one_work+0x1fd/0x400
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  worker_thread+0x34/0x410
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  kthread+0x121/0x140
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ? process_one_work+0x400/0x400
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ? kthread_park+0xb0/0xb0
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x40
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] ---[ end trace 2d48809a48480d0d ]---
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] p2p-dev-wlo2:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x0
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 12028 at /build/linux-hwe-FLYqTt/linux-hwe-5.0.0/net/mac80211/driver-ops.h:19 drv_remove_interface+0xfe/0x110 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] Modules linked in: hid_generic usbhid ccm rfcomm bnep nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_skl snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_soc_sst_dsp ledtrig_audio snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_compress intel_rapl ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel intel_telemetry_pltdrv intel_punit_ipc intel_telemetry_core snd_hda_codec intel_pmc_ipc snd_hda_core snd_hwdep x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event i915 snd_rawmidi kvmgt vfio_mdev mdev aesni_intel arc4 vfio_iommu_type1 vfio aes_x86_64 crypto_simd snd_seq cryptd glue_helper kvm intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf snd_seq_device snd_timer btusb iwlmvm btrtl mac80211 irqbypass btbcm btintel input_leds bluetooth serio_raw iwlwifi drm_kms_helper wmi_bmof drm snd ecdh_generic i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops syscopyarea cfg80211 sysfillrect
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  sysimgblt rtsx_pci_ms soundcore mei_me memstick mei mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 rtsx_pci_sdmmc sdhci_pci r8169 ahci realtek rtsx_pci libahci psmouse cqhci sdhci i2c_hid hid wmi pinctrl_geminilake pinctrl_intel video
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] CPU: 0 PID: 12028 Comm: kworker/0:1 Tainted: G        W         5.0.0-37-generic #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] Hardware name: Intel(R) Client Systems NUC7CJYH/NUC7JYB, BIOS JYGLKCPX.86A.0050.2019.0418.1441 04/18/2019
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] Workqueue: events_freezable ieee80211_restart_work [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] RIP: 0010:drv_remove_interface+0xfe/0x110 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] Code: 75 e8 5b 41 5c 41 5d 5d c3 48 8b b3 40 04 00 00 48 81 c3 60 04 00 00 48 c7 c7 08 d9 60 c0 48 85 f6 48 0f 44 f3 e8 a2 7c 70 e2 <0f> 0b 5b 41 5c 41 5d 5d c3 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] RSP: 0018:ffffa24fc1563cc0 EFLAGS: 00010282
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8f17f5324460 RCX: 0000000000000006
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] RDX: 0000000000000007 RSI: 0000000000000086 RDI: ffff8f17f7e16440
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] RBP: ffffa24fc1563cd8 R08: 00000000000003e6 R09: 0000000000000004
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] R10: ffffa24fc23dbd68 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff8f17f32987a0
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] R13: ffff8f17f3298f28 R14: ffff8f17f32987a0 R15: ffff8f17f5324b18
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8f17f7e00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] CR2: 00007f267cf01000 CR3: 000000019060e000 CR4: 0000000000340ef0
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] Call Trace:
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ieee80211_do_stop+0x4e8/0x830 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ? do_invalid_op+0x3b/0x50
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ieee80211_sdata_stop+0x1e/0x30 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ieee80211_stop_p2p_device+0x12/0x20 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  cfg80211_stop_p2p_device+0x6d/0x1a0 [cfg80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  cfg80211_shutdown_all_interfaces+0x96/0xd0 [cfg80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ieee80211_handle_reconfig_failure+0x98/0xb0 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ieee80211_reconfig+0x230/0x1250 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ieee80211_restart_work+0xc0/0xf0 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  process_one_work+0x1fd/0x400
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  worker_thread+0x34/0x410
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  kthread+0x121/0x140
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ? process_one_work+0x400/0x400
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ? kthread_park+0xb0/0xb0
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x40
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] ---[ end trace 2d48809a48480d0e ]---
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] wlo2: deauthenticating from f8:e7:1e:16:cc:1c by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] wlo2:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x0
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 12028 at /build/linux-hwe-FLYqTt/linux-hwe-5.0.0/net/mac80211/driver-ops.h:19 __ieee80211_flush_queues+0x1a4/0x1b0 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] Modules linked in: hid_generic usbhid ccm rfcomm bnep nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_skl snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_soc_sst_dsp ledtrig_audio snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_compress intel_rapl ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel intel_telemetry_pltdrv intel_punit_ipc intel_telemetry_core snd_hda_codec intel_pmc_ipc snd_hda_core snd_hwdep x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event i915 snd_rawmidi kvmgt vfio_mdev mdev aesni_intel arc4 vfio_iommu_type1 vfio aes_x86_64 crypto_simd snd_seq cryptd glue_helper kvm intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf snd_seq_device snd_timer btusb iwlmvm btrtl mac80211 irqbypass btbcm btintel input_leds bluetooth serio_raw iwlwifi drm_kms_helper wmi_bmof drm snd ecdh_generic i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops syscopyarea cfg80211 sysfillrect
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  sysimgblt rtsx_pci_ms soundcore mei_me memstick mei mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 rtsx_pci_sdmmc sdhci_pci r8169 ahci realtek rtsx_pci libahci psmouse cqhci sdhci i2c_hid hid wmi pinctrl_geminilake pinctrl_intel video
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] CPU: 0 PID: 12028 Comm: kworker/0:1 Tainted: G        W         5.0.0-37-generic #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] Hardware name: Intel(R) Client Systems NUC7CJYH/NUC7JYB, BIOS JYGLKCPX.86A.0050.2019.0418.1441 04/18/2019
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] Workqueue: events_freezable ieee80211_restart_work [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] RIP: 0010:__ieee80211_flush_queues+0x1a4/0x1b0 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] Code: 00 00 00 00 e9 0f ff ff ff 49 8b b5 40 04 00 00 49 81 c5 60 04 00 00 48 c7 c7 f8 05 61 c0 48 85 f6 49 0f 44 f5 e8 1c 16 6d e2 <0f> 0b e9 1a ff ff ff 0f 1f 44 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 0f b6 ca 31
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] RSP: 0018:ffffa24fc1563948 EFLAGS: 00010282
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8f17f32987a0 RCX: 0000000000000006
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] RDX: 0000000000000007 RSI: 0000000000000096 RDI: ffff8f17f7e16440
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] RBP: ffffa24fc1563978 R08: 000000000000040b R09: 0000000000000004
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] R10: ffffa24fc2717d68 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: 0000000000000074
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] R13: ffff8f17f0f06da0 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: 0000000000000074
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8f17f7e00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] CR2: 00007f267cf01000 CR3: 000000019060e000 CR4: 0000000000340ef0
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] Call Trace:
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ieee80211_flush_queues+0x13/0x20 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ieee80211_set_disassoc+0x341/0x5d0 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ieee80211_mgd_deauth+0x28b/0x450 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ieee80211_deauth+0x18/0x20 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  cfg80211_mlme_deauth+0xaf/0x1c0 [cfg80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  cfg80211_mlme_down+0x66/0x80 [cfg80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  cfg80211_disconnect+0x12b/0x1e0 [cfg80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  __cfg80211_leave+0x141/0x1a0 [cfg80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  cfg80211_leave+0x2b/0x40 [cfg80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  cfg80211_netdev_notifier_call+0x253/0x5b0 [cfg80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ? fixup_bug.part.12+0x1c/0x40
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ? inetdev_event+0x46/0x570
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ? skb_dequeue+0x59/0x70
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  notifier_call_chain+0x4c/0x70
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  raw_notifier_call_chain+0x16/0x20
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  call_netdevice_notifiers_info+0x2d/0x60
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  __dev_close_many+0x63/0x120
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  dev_close_many+0x8c/0x140
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  dev_close.part.98+0x4a/0x70
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  dev_close+0x19/0x20
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  cfg80211_shutdown_all_interfaces+0x77/0xd0 [cfg80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ieee80211_handle_reconfig_failure+0x98/0xb0 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ieee80211_reconfig+0x230/0x1250 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ieee80211_restart_work+0xc0/0xf0 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  process_one_work+0x1fd/0x400
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  worker_thread+0x34/0x410
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  kthread+0x121/0x140
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ? process_one_work+0x400/0x400
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ? kthread_park+0xb0/0xb0
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x40
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] ---[ end trace 2d48809a48480d0f ]---
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] wlo2:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x0
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 12028 at /build/linux-hwe-FLYqTt/linux-hwe-5.0.0/net/mac80211/driver-ops.h:19 __ieee80211_flush_queues+0x1a4/0x1b0 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] Modules linked in: hid_generic usbhid ccm rfcomm bnep nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_skl snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_soc_sst_dsp ledtrig_audio snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_compress intel_rapl ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel intel_telemetry_pltdrv intel_punit_ipc intel_telemetry_core snd_hda_codec intel_pmc_ipc snd_hda_core snd_hwdep x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event i915 snd_rawmidi kvmgt vfio_mdev mdev aesni_intel arc4 vfio_iommu_type1 vfio aes_x86_64 crypto_simd snd_seq cryptd glue_helper kvm intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf snd_seq_device snd_timer btusb iwlmvm btrtl mac80211 irqbypass btbcm btintel input_leds bluetooth serio_raw iwlwifi drm_kms_helper wmi_bmof drm snd ecdh_generic i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops syscopyarea cfg80211 sysfillrect
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  sysimgblt rtsx_pci_ms soundcore mei_me memstick mei mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 rtsx_pci_sdmmc sdhci_pci r8169 ahci realtek rtsx_pci libahci psmouse cqhci sdhci i2c_hid hid wmi pinctrl_geminilake pinctrl_intel video
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] CPU: 0 PID: 12028 Comm: kworker/0:1 Tainted: G        W         5.0.0-37-generic #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] Hardware name: Intel(R) Client Systems NUC7CJYH/NUC7JYB, BIOS JYGLKCPX.86A.0050.2019.0418.1441 04/18/2019
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] Workqueue: events_freezable ieee80211_restart_work [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] RIP: 0010:__ieee80211_flush_queues+0x1a4/0x1b0 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] Code: 00 00 00 00 e9 0f ff ff ff 49 8b b5 40 04 00 00 49 81 c5 60 04 00 00 48 c7 c7 f8 05 61 c0 48 85 f6 49 0f 44 f5 e8 1c 16 6d e2 <0f> 0b e9 1a ff ff ff 0f 1f 44 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 0f b6 ca 31
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] RSP: 0018:ffffa24fc1563948 EFLAGS: 00010282
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8f17f32987a0 RCX: 0000000000000006
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] RDX: 0000000000000007 RSI: 0000000000000096 RDI: ffff8f17f7e16440
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] RBP: ffffa24fc1563978 R08: 000000000000043e R09: 0000000000000004
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] R10: ffffa24fc15638a0 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: 0000000000000074
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] R13: ffff8f17f0f06da0 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000074
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8f17f7e00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] CR2: 00007f267cf01000 CR3: 000000019060e000 CR4: 0000000000340ef0
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] Call Trace:
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ieee80211_flush_queues+0x13/0x20 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ieee80211_set_disassoc+0x398/0x5d0 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ieee80211_mgd_deauth+0x28b/0x450 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ieee80211_deauth+0x18/0x20 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  cfg80211_mlme_deauth+0xaf/0x1c0 [cfg80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  cfg80211_mlme_down+0x66/0x80 [cfg80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  cfg80211_disconnect+0x12b/0x1e0 [cfg80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  __cfg80211_leave+0x141/0x1a0 [cfg80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  cfg80211_leave+0x2b/0x40 [cfg80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  cfg80211_netdev_notifier_call+0x253/0x5b0 [cfg80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ? fixup_bug.part.12+0x1c/0x40
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ? inetdev_event+0x46/0x570
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ? skb_dequeue+0x59/0x70
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  notifier_call_chain+0x4c/0x70
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  raw_notifier_call_chain+0x16/0x20
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  call_netdevice_notifiers_info+0x2d/0x60
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  __dev_close_many+0x63/0x120
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  dev_close_many+0x8c/0x140
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  dev_close.part.98+0x4a/0x70
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  dev_close+0x19/0x20
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  cfg80211_shutdown_all_interfaces+0x77/0xd0 [cfg80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ieee80211_handle_reconfig_failure+0x98/0xb0 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ieee80211_reconfig+0x230/0x1250 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ieee80211_restart_work+0xc0/0xf0 [mac80211]
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  process_one_work+0x1fd/0x400
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  worker_thread+0x34/0x410
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  kthread+0x121/0x140
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ? process_one_work+0x400/0x400
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ? kthread_park+0xb0/0xb0
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019]  ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x40
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] ---[ end trace 2d48809a48480d10 ]---
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] wlo2:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x0
[Sat Dec  7 04:53:33 2019] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 12028 at /build/linux-hwe-FLYqTt/linux-hwe-5.0.0/net/mac80211/driver-ops.h:19 drv_ampdu_action+0x13a/0x150 [mac80211]
```

Comment: This looks like a kernel bug to me due to a crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the driver with one downloaded from intel appears to have fixed the problem.  In my case I downloaded `iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.618819.0.tgz` from:  https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi

After copying it to the system, I compared that with the one in `/lib/firmware` (same filename) and the files were different, so I saved the existing one and then replaced it with the one downloaded from intel.

Comment: Any thoughts on how best to check if this is a distro problem / report it?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove and reinsert the WiFi driver rather than rebooting:

```
/sbin/modprobe -v -r iwldvm # This removes iwlwifi too
/sbin/modprobe -v iwlwifi   # This starts iwldvm too
systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

The last line is optional and you can save time if it's not needed. The above commands are for an Intel WiFi card. To get a list of your WiFi drivers use:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
       logical name: enp59s0
       version: 10
       serial: 28:f1:0e:2a:1a:ed
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=192.168.0.12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:16 memory:dd600000-dd63ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3c:00.0
       logical name: wlp60s0
       version: 32
       serial: 9c:b6:d0:10:37:f7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.14.153-0414153-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.0.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:137 memory:dd200000-dd3fffff
```

Notice the the WiFi information above in **bold**.

Then see if what is tied to the driver:

```
$ lsmod | grep ath10k_pci
ath10k_pci             53248  0
ath10k_core           417792  1 ath10k_pci
```

In this case all we need to do is remove `ath10k_pci` driver and reload it.

```
$ sudo modprobe -r -v ath10k_pci
rmmod ath10k_pci
rmmod ath10k_core
rmmod mac80211
rmmod ath
rmmod cfg80211

$ lsmod | grep ath10k_pci # Nothing appears so we've successfully removed driver!

$ sudo modprobe -v ath10k_pci
insmod /lib/modules/4.14.153-0414153-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.14.153-0414153-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.14.153-0414153-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.14.153-0414153-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_core.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.14.153-0414153-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_pci.ko
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this next time it goes down.  FYI the driver is iwlwifi which I believe is generic, so it might help if I can get the intel-specific one.

Comment: The `i` in `iwlwifi` stands for Intel. From google search: `iwlwifi` is the wireless driver for Intel's current wireless chips. For older chips, there are other drivers: `ipw2100`. `ipw2200`. `iwlegacy` (for Intel® PRO/Wireless 3945ABG and Intel® Wireless Wi-Fi Link 4965AGN)

Comment: Thank you - this was helpful

Comment: Thanks for the answer; the first two commands help to repair wifi.