# Ubuntu Powersave setting change error: syntax error near line 1 << What now?

Tags: wireless

I'm attempting to change a setting in the following file:

/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf

...and change the setting from

```
wifi.powersave = 3
```

to

```
wifi.powersave = 2
```

based on the recommendations here: [WiFi randomly disconnected on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030653/wifi-randomly-disconnected-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

However I get the following error after editing and saving the file in vim:

```
>>> /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf: syntax error near line 1 <<< 

What now?
```

There are four errors like this before the "What now?" - two for line 1 and two for line 2. Any recommendations? Just attempting to fix a Wifi connection issue. Thanks.

Comment: Are you somehow editing the file using `visudo` rather than `vim` itself? What does `type -a vim` say?

Comment: You're right - it was actually visudo. Looked up how to quit and save with visudo and the change is now saved and working. Thanks.