# Wifi constantly stops working, randomly, Intel

Tags: wireless, 19.10, iwlwifi

I have a Lenovo X1 Carbon running Ubuntu 19.10

About a month ago my wifi started randomly breaking. When it did this the Wifi would still say connected status.

To fix it when this happens I need to do `sudo service network-manager restart`, every 5 mins or so.

Things I've tried:

- Disable ipv6
- Disable wifi power management (https://askubuntu.com/a/1077559/1072078)
- `sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms`
- And a few other things I can't remember

`sudo lshw -C network` gives the following output:

```bsh
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 78
       serial: 5c:5f:67:f5:4f:06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-7629-generic firmware=36.77d01142.0 ip=192.168.8.105 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:161 memory:ee300000-ee301fff
```

Any idea on how i can resolve this? it's driving me slightly crazy.

edit:

`dmseg` output:

```
[784119.946464] mce: CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
[784119.946466] mce: CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[784466.571328] mce: CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 5305767)
[784466.571329] mce: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 5305768)
[784466.571379] mce: CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 5305768)
[784466.571380] mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 5305765)
[784466.571381] mce: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 5305770)
[784466.571381] mce: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 5305769)
[784466.571383] mce: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 5305769)
[784466.571383] mce: CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 5305767)
[784466.580272] mce: CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[784466.580273] mce: CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
[784466.580274] mce: CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
[784466.580275] mce: CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
[784466.580275] mce: CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[784466.580276] mce: CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
[784466.580277] mce: CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[784466.580277] mce: CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[784487.553265] mce: CPU0: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 558531)
[784487.553266] mce: CPU4: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 558531)
[784487.556285] mce: CPU0: Core temperature/speed normal
[784487.556286] mce: CPU4: Core temperature/speed normal
```

Comment: Can you add the last lines of `dmesg` to your message?

Comment: @kcdtv ive added that .

Comment: it is not here... search for some event related to your wifi in dmesg and paste it here-

Comment: it is there, see above.

Comment: I see the stdout but what is not there is the event related to your issue, everything you posted is about the CPU. dmesg is long, go backward in the shell find elements related to networking and post them here