# Wifi Fluctuates with No Internet Available

Tags: networking, 18.04, internet, dns

I am on Ubuntu 18.04
My home wifi connection frequently flickers in and out of Internet once every 2-3 minutes.
The Wi-fi symbol tends to show a question mark during the time there is no internet but sometimes even when there is.

I have tried setting alternate DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) but it did not help.
During the time it is under no Internet I try to `ping 8.8.8.8` but it shows a 100% packet loss along with Destination Host Unreachable.

This problem is occurring only on this particular network and this particular device (It is working fine with another network available). I have a Dual-Boot with Windows which works completely fine with this network along with several other devices.

I have the following network adapter:
Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter

Comment: Have you tried using this article: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030653/wifi-randomly-disconnected-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts.

Comment: It did not work for me.