# Regular loss of wifi connection

Tags: networking, wireless, xubuntu, internet

I have strange, regular connection losses: Currently, approximately every two minutes, I cannot establish connections via wifi although the wifi notification does not signal any disconnects. I wrote a script that logs these connection losses (the test runs about once per second and simply tests whether google.com can be reached). Here's part of the result:

```
2020-11-30 19:38:03.652132
2020-11-30 19:38:04.662507
2020-11-30 19:40:03.420690
2020-11-30 19:40:04.645271
2020-11-30 19:42:03.510320
2020-11-30 19:42:04.643497
2020-11-30 19:44:03.574795
2020-11-30 19:46:03.616409
2020-11-30 19:46:04.647914
2020-11-30 19:48:03.491386
2020-11-30 19:48:04.655880
2020-11-30 19:48:24.671726
2020-11-30 19:50:03.494267
2020-11-30 19:50:04.627566
2020-11-30 19:50:24.036448
2020-11-30 19:50:25.045478
2020-11-30 19:52:03.507604
```

I already ran `journalctl --follow` but it did not show entries with the observed frequency.
I have deactivated IPv6 and wifi powersaving (as suggested here: [WiFi randomly disconnected on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030653/wifi-randomly-disconnected-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts)).
The system is a pretty new and unmodified Xubuntu 20.04 installation. With the old installation of Xubuntu 18.04, the same problem occurred.
Any ideas what the underlying problem might be and how it could be debugged or even solved?

Edit:

@waltinator requested the output of

```
sudo rfkill list; nmcli con show; ip link; ip route;sudo lshw  -C network
```

Here it is:

```
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE          
aethernet           5456f5b9-03b6-4e82-bf28-7b6c5196eab3  wifi      wlp2s0          
br-e9214b077133     0cf6997e-0276-4fab-aac3-237b360e0dc8  bridge    br-e9214b077133 
docker0             6dc33bfb-424e-40a9-a1d7-f9cef7ca836a  bridge    docker0         
Wired connection 1  a3fba10c-4077-3086-a22b-c76bb530b7b0  ethernet  --              
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp1s0f1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:76:1c:2e:7c:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c4:85:08:86:9a:a7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:b5:59:b2:51 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br-e9214b077133: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:00:d1:bd:f6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
default via 192.168.178.1 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-e9214b077133 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.178.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.54 metric 600 
SCSI                        
  *-network        
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       logical name: enp1s0f1
       version: 12
       serial: f0:76:1c:2e:7c:80
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b0504000-b0504fff memory:b0500000-b0503fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6235
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 24
       serial: c4:85:08:86:9a:a7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-56-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.178.54 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:47 memory:b0400000-b0401fff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: br-e9214b077133
       serial: 02:42:00:d1:bd:f6
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.18.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: docker0
       serial: 02:42:b5:59:b2:51
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
```

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: @waltinator: I already looked at all the logs with ```journalctl --follow``` without getting any error messages. Also ```sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager``` does not show any problems.

Comment: I have a script to wait until connection drops, then do a user-specified action (to bring connection up) and go back to waiting. See https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic

Comment: @waltinator The script seems useful if a method for reconnecting is known but I have no idea what causes the disconnects nor what to do in order to reconnect.

Comment: Read `man nmcli ip-link ip-monitor ip-address ;man 7 regex`

Comment: Please [Edit] your question and show us `sudo rfkill list; nmcli con show; ip link; ip route;sudo lshw  -C network`. Do not respond in comments.