# Ubuntu 20.04 wifi randomly disconnecting after update

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04

### The problem

Recently I updated ubuntu 20.04 on my lenovo laptop and since the update, the wifi is disconnected at random intervals all the time. I had this problem before and disabling ipv6 according to https://askubuntu.com/a/1180403/1191580 seemed to solve it. After updating however, this solution does not work anymore. Furthermore, the wifi power saving option is already off.

### Wireless adapter info:

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at a1100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ce
    Kernel modules: rtl8821ce
```

### Update:

After further investigation, I also discovered the fact that my wifi disconnected randomly when using voice/video chat software (Discord and Zoom). After several tests to verify this, I applied the suggestion as mentioned by **i9pp0**, which seems to have solved the problem. I hope this can help anyone else experiencing a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to update your drivers. Give this a try:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall git dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
cd rtl8821ce
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
chmod +x dkms-remove.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Reboot

Make sure that secure boot is disabled before starting.