# WiFi randomly disconnected on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, network-manager

I have a problem with Wifi connection with Ubuntu. Basically, many times at random time intervals wifi connection stops and cannot load the pages in the browser. In addition,  the icon keeps the full signal. In order to connect again in the wifi network, I turn off and on the wifi.

I have searched some other threads like [this thread from ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030653/wifi-randomly-disconnected-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts) and applied the solution but the problem is still here.

In addition, I have tried to connect my PC in different routers but I face the same problem.

As suggested in the comment I copied some lines from logs,

```
NetworkManager[1128]: <info>  [1624633925.6288] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set disabled
NetworkManager[1128]: <info>  [1624633925.6289] device (wlp9s0): state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[1128]: <info>  [1624633925.6550] dhcp4 (wlp9s0): canceled DHCP transaction
NetworkManager[1128]: <info>  [1624633925.6550] dhcp4 (wlp9s0): state changed bound -> done
NetworkManager[1128]: <info>  [1624633925.6557] dhcp6 (wlp9s0): canceled DHCP transaction
NetworkManager[1128]: <info>  [1624633925.6557] dhcp6 (wlp9s0): state changed bound -> done
NetworkManager[1128]: <info>  [1624633925.6627] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
NetworkManager[1128]: <info>  [1624633925.6674] audit: op="radio-control" arg="wireless-enabled" pid=1588 uid=1000 resul>
NetworkManager[1128]: <info>  [1624633925.6682] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi now disabled by radio killswitch
NetworkManager[1128]: <info>  [1624633925.6707] device (p2p-dev-wlp9s0): state change: disconnected -> unavailable (reas>
NetworkManager[1128]: <info>  [1624633928.4432] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
```

To conclude, I cannot find the source of this error and why WiFi is failing some times.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Answer (score -1):

try this :
change `wifi.powersave = 3` to `wifi.powersave = 2` in /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf

refer to [WiFi randomly disconnected on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030653/wifi-randomly-disconnected-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

Answer (score -3):

You should try these command

```
1.sudo apt install net-tools
2.sudo ifconfig
3.sudo ifconfig <yourwirelessinterface> down
4.sudo service networking restart
5.sudo ifconfig <yourwirelessinterface> up
6.sudo reboot
```