# HP laptop, no internet connection after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, upgrade, 18.04

Since I have upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 I have problems with the internet connection.

To overcome temporarily this problem I have edited the resolv.conf file inserting the nameserver 8.8.8.8 (following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1021885)) and that works, but everytime I log in I have to edit the file again.

Here is some information I collected with wireless-info script posted on this forum.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 18 Aug 2018 09:50 -03 -0300

Booted last: 18 Aug 2018 00:00 -03 -0300

Script from: 10 Jan 2018 20:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.15.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 10 17:58:07 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 [8086:8070]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev
 0a)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [103c:8093]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b50d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

hp_wmi                 16384  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
iwlmvm                364544  0
mac80211              778240  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               282624  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              622592  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
wmi                    24576  2 wmi_bmof,hp_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether <MAC address>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 22558  bytes 1464002 (1.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 22558  bytes 1464002 (1.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.6  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::9bde:cfee:a95a:a4e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether <MAC address>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 30631  bytes 35395691 (35.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 26110  bytes 3967998 (3.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"C3-P0"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'C3-P0' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=135 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-33 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:241   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      2703     1  0 09:41 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Wireless 3160 (Dual Band Wireless AC 3160)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         iwlwifi
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.15.0-32-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               17.948900127.0
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:08:00.0/net/wlan0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlan0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     C3-P0 2
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       c6199fb6-ad2a-476d-92b5-46b318ddffaa
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     150 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.6/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.0.1, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.0.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.175.1.5
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.8.8
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          domain.name
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        domain_name_servers = 10.175.1.5 8.8.8.8
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.0.255
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 7200
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       ip_address = 192.168.0.6
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       domain_name = domain.name
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       expiry = 1534603283
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       routers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       network_number = 192.168.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.0.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::9bde:cfee:a95a:a4e/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::1e5f:2bff:fe9c:305a
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ::/0, nh = fe80::1e5f:2bff:fe9c:305a, mt = 600
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 600
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{17,22,5,33,1,18}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   (null) | (null)
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   c6199fb6-ad2a-476d-92b5-46b318ddffaa | C3-P0 2
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[3]:   (null) | (null)
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[4]:   (null) | (null)
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[5]:   5eb0907e-d662-47f0-aa4c-5ac23ffd4792 | Denys
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[6]:   (null) | (null)

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               rtl8107e-2_0.0.2 02/26/15
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:09:00.0/net/eth0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID                  BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  IN-USE 
rabito                <MAC 'rabito' [AN1]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  405 Mbit/s  99      ▂▄▆█  WPA2       no             
C3-P0                 <MAC 'C3-P0' [AC1]>  Infra  2     2417 MHz  270 Mbit/s  85      ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2  yes     *      
Dirac                 <MAC 'Dirac' [AC8]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  135 Mbit/s  62      ▂▄▆_  WPA2       no             
--                    <MAC '
Kaza12                <MAC 'Kaza12' [AC9]>  Infra  7     2442 MHz  270 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no             
THOMAS                <MAC 'THOMAS' [AC10]>  Infra  7     2442 MHz  135 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA1       no             
TP-LINK_Renato e Sam  <MAC 'TP-LINK_Renato e Sam' [AC6]>  Infra  2     2417 MHz  270 Mbit/s  25      ▂___  WPA2       no             
ISAIAS                <MAC 'ISAIAS' [AC14]>  Infra  8     2447 MHz  135 Mbit/s  20      ▂___  WPA1       no             
TP-Link_AB99          <MAC 'TP-Link_AB99' [AC7]>  Infra  3     2422 MHz  270 Mbit/s  17      ▂___  WPA2       no             
PEDROSANET            <MAC 'PEDROSANET' [AC11]>  Infra  7     2442 MHz  135 Mbit/s  17      ▂___  WPA1       no             
Evellyn               <MAC 'Evellyn' [AC2]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  130 Mbit/s  15      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2  no             
Timba uaifay          <MAC 'Timba uaifay' [AC3]>  Infra  2     2417 MHz  135 Mbit/s  15      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2  no             
Julia                 <MAC 'Julia' [AC5]>  Infra  2     2417 MHz  135 Mbit/s  15      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2  no             
Zion                  <MAC 'Zion' [AN14]>  Infra  7     2442 MHz  270 Mbit/s  15      ▂___  WPA1       no             
CASAAOLADO            <MAC 'CASAAOLADO' [AN15]>  Infra  8     2447 MHz  135 Mbit/s  15      ▂___  WPA2       no             
ALECSANDRA            <MAC 'ALECSANDRA' [AN16]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  135 Mbit/s  12      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2  no             

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=false

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=<MAC address>,

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Recife (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Current Frequency=2.417 GHz (Channel 2)

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      2   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      6   APs on   Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      3   APs on   Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

##### module infos ######################

[iwlmvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     8459DFE0C7E84CD497647AA
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlmvm
vermagic:       4.15.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)
parm:           tfd_q_hang_detect:TFD queues hang detection (default: true (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-32-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     1CEA5CF286EDB289C1D0BF8
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-a0-jf-a0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-jf-b0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-jf-a0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-a0-hr-a0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-a0-jf-b0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-f0-hr-a0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-jf-b0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-hr-a0-34.ucode
srcversion:     6BA065AF04F0DFDB8D91DBF
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       4.15.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)
parm:           d0i3_timeout:Timeout to D0i3 entry when idle (ms) (uint)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-32-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     D5B0789D4C423C81CCFB437
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2
tfd_q_hang_detect: Y

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
d0i3_disable: Y
d0i3_timeout: 1000
disable_11ac: N
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: 3

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp

coretemp

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/RTL8101.conf]
options RTL8101 fwlps=N

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

[/etc/pm/sleep.d/config.d] (644 dsantos)
SUSPEND_MODULES="RTL8101"

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8136 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="et
h0"
# PCI device 0x8086:0x08b3 (iwlwifi)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="w
lan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   29.356833] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.948900127.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   29.490190] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3160, REV=0x164
[   29.513296] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: base HW address: <MAC address>
[   30.240063] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.1.2d.d.bseq
[   30.353550] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[   30.564788] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   48.519076] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   48.618788] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth0: link down
[   48.618901] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   48.700753] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready (repeated 5 times)
[   68.665461] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'C3-P0' [AC1]>
[   68.672786] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'C3-P0' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   68.676380] wlan0: authenticated
[   68.680039] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'C3-P0' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   68.684523] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'C3-P0' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[   68.693769] wlan0: associated
[   68.787644] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[  173.359156] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'C3-P0' [AC1]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  174.598151] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  174.603466] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready (repeated 5 times)
[  182.134280] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'C3-P0' [AC1]>
[  182.139124] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'C3-P0' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  182.146237] wlan0: authenticated
[  182.148134] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'C3-P0' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  182.158534] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'C3-P0' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[  182.170864] wlan0: associated
[  182.238242] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: That's the same issue I had when upgrading to 18.04. You have half of the fix. Here's a link to the solution I found, https://askubuntu.com/a/1021885/858472.

Comment: That was really usefull. Thanks a lot for the link.