# Ubuntu home network can't connect to firefox server

Tags: networking

My home network has 2 desktops, 1 laptop, 1 printer, and 1 smart TV.  All equipment is connected through a modem/router.  The desktops are ethernet wired to the router while the laptop, printer and TV are connected by WiFi. Everything worked fine on Ubuntu 16.04LTS until I upgraded one of the desktops (grumpy) from Ubuntu 16.04LTS to Ubuntu 18.04.1LTS.

ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com  on grumpy yields "Name or service not known".
ping -c3 8.8.8.8 yields 3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss
Mozilla Firefox on grumpy cannot find any server anymore.  None of the of the Preferences/General/Network Proxy/Settings options work! Printing from grumpy does not work either! Unexpectedly, Grumpy shows on Settings/Network/Wired/"Connected-1000 Mb/s".

Everything on my home network works - but grumpy (with Ubuntu 18.04.1LTS)! 
How can I make grumpy work again? Note: I want to keep my existing data. on grumpy intact.

See inside [No internet after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021884/no-internet-after-upgrade-from-16-04-to-18-04).

Solution:
Start the terminal and type:
$ ifconfig

Now you gotta figure out which is your Ethernet interface. Mine is listed as eth0.

Next type:
$sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces

My file only had:

```
 # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

 auto lo

 iface lo inet loopback
```

Now what you need to do is to add the following lines afterwards:

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet dhcp

Lastly, 
$ sudo ifup eth0

reboot and you're done. Don't forget to change eth0 with the name of your Ethernet interface.

Original answer
shareedit
edited Sep 19 at 9:37
Yufenyuy Veyeh Dider
1,3902923
answered Sep 19 at 9:08
Whatnow
211

Comment: On grumpy, open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run: `ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com` and also: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` Next, edit your question to add the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18.04 does not work with eth0 or eth1 (example: enp2s0, wlp1s0, etc) and does not work with /etc/network/interfaces (See [Yaml](http://www.yamllint.com/))

Create a file:

```
/etc/netplan/config.yaml
```

And add your localnet config. Example:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system (networkd)
network:
  version: 2
# change to "networkd" if you don't want to use NetworkManager
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
# change dhcp4 to "no" if you want to use static IP. See http://yaml.org/type/bool.html
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: no
      #addresses: [192.168.88.13/24] # uncomment and replace with your static IP/Netmask 
      #gateway4: 192.168.88.1 # uncomment and replace with your gateway
      #nameservers:
      #addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]  # uncomment and replace with your dns
   enp2s8:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.10/24]
```

You must validate this content first in [yamllint](http://www.yamllint.com/)

For more information visit [NetPlan](https://netplan.io/examples)