# DNS resolution fails post Ubuntu upgrade from 16.04 to 18.0.4 using do-release-upgrade

Tags: dns, do-release-upgrade

I tried to upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 using the `do-release-upgrade` command and post upgrade DNS resolution is failing. My actual intention is to go to 20.04, but since I am on 16.04, I have to go to 18.04 first.

Ping works fine for the google IP but DNS alone fails. I added `nameserver 8.8.8.8` in `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` based on solution provided in [No internet after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021884/no-internet-after-upgrade-from-16-04-to-18-04), but when I try to restart networking (sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart), it fails with the below error:

```
Restarting networking (via systemctl): networking.serviceJob for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!

systemctl status networking.service
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-09-05 08:25:00 IST; 22s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 4082 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 4070 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4082 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

How to fix this? Or is there a way to do a clean upgrade again which will fix all these issues?

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support  *Ubuntu PRO & Ubuntu ESM are Canonical services, and not part of community support, this is a community support site*

Comment: How to upgrade to 20.04 without DNS now? My actual intention is to go to 20.04 but since i was on 16.04, i had to go to 18.04 first

Comment: Your question (*as written*) doesn't say that, and is off-topic. It's also not clear and specific (Ubuntu Desktop? Ubuntu Server? which kernel stack [default set by install media]) & being a EOSS release, our ability to explore details is reduced. You can *non-destructively* re-install a Desktop system; which is what I'd do; or if server you just *clean* install then restore you data., but as 18.04 now requires ESM or Pro to be enabled to fully-upgrade (*should be if you used it at 16.04*) you've left it too late for community support except for a *working* 18.04 system upgrade to 20.04