# How to install 18.04//?

Tags: upgrade

Last Sunday or Monday  I posted a question that boiled down to:;
How to install 18.04?  say, starting by 15 April.  My desktop is having
trouble with 17.04 and 17.10.  Screwy!

Okay, I'll try again.  I messed up 7.04 And 7.10 on my largest desktop.
(I'm writing this on my laptop.)  What I want to do is install 18.04
Om my desktop and go from  there.  I've been using Ubuntu since 5.04 LTS
And have stuck with it.  A disability limits me to the use of only my
left hand.
A friend who lives 2000 miles away configured a RAID when he was here last
Fall.  He is a new father and cant fly back until 2019. He said that
Installing Ubuntu 18.04 Would be "very difficult".  Considering my hassles
With 17.04 And 17.10, I thought installing 18.04 LTS and staying there
Would be my best bet.  This is one of the few times I've had this much
troubles with Ubuntu;  previously I have  waited at least until the middle
of April.

To Anybody:
Do I have to create a DVD  with 18.04?  What is a "Start Up Disk"?

Thanks to Richard G for his suggestions.

Gary Kline

PS:  The above was my post within the past week++; it is for anybody in the Ubuntu community.  What's the best way of upgrading to 18.04?  I have only        2 DVDs left!

Comment: 18.04 is currently in Beta, but wait until the 26th of April and then it will be stable and you can install the same way you install the same way you install any other version.

Comment: [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso). You lose (miserable package management issues) if you don't wait until April 26, 2018, the official Ubuntu 18.04 release date.

Comment: [Ubuntu Development version / How to participate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate)

Comment: AskUbuntu is focusing on released versions of Ubuntu. Please search for help at other forums, for example the Ubuntu Forum for the developing version. There is a link via my previous comment.

Comment: _“I have only 2 DVDs left!”_ So if you don’t have a free USB drive available and are afraid of losing DVDs, you should definitely wait about 2 weeks for the official release.

Comment: All right, I  have waited two weeks;  I am at 17.04.  How do I  upgrade to 17.10?