# Problem booting with GeForce 940MX

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, 18.04

I have an issue while booting Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver, development edition).

I freshly installed it, and after the reboot (started from terminal) it stops at the checklist. At the second try it showed some problems with the nvidia 940MX GPU.

Can I somehow fix it? Should I reinstall 17.10?

The computer in question is an Acer Aspire F15, intel i5, nvidia GeForce 940MX GPU (Also Intel HD-Graphics, but I switched to Nvidia, which I guess might have caused the problem).

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: [Ubuntu Development version / How to participate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate)

Comment: 18.04 isn't officially released yet until April 26th. Before that date, we don't really support questions about it here, because development releases are off-topic. You can write a bug report on Launchpad instead.

Comment: @ByteCommander Note that, although most questions about development releases are off-topic on Ask Ubuntu, *including this question*, [we do allow *some* such questions](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/872/22949).

Comment: I faced the same on 17.10. It helped me to downgrade to `4.13.0-16` kernel: `version=4.13.0-16-generic && for thing in linux-image-$version linux-image-extra-$version linux-headers-$version linux-firmware; do apt-get download $(apt-rdepends $thing | grep -v "^ " | sed 's/debconf-2.0/debconf/g'); done`.