# Broken input in Gnome (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: gnome, mouse, touchpad, 18.04, gnome-shell-extension

Not sure if it's something I did but couple of days ago, after a reboot, any sort of input completely stopped working in Gnome. Keyboard, touchpad clicks, USB mouse clicks, etc. The cursor still moves, however and the keyboard also starts responding sometimes after a very long wait.

Tried purging and re-installing a lot of packages, but in vain. Then it hit me to try Unity (7) and voila, everything works perfectly here. I waited for a couple of days to see if the devs would release some patch but no, input in Gnome is still frozen.

So, any help please? I'd really like to resolve this without installing the system all over again

Comment: That's a bug then, kindly report it: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: Maybe you can find help at the Ubuntu Forum for the developing release, [Ubuntu Development version / How to participate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As michael has correctly pointed out, the cause of the issue was in fact an extension called Workspaces to Dock. [Here's the issue on Github](https://github.com/passingthru67/workspaces-to-dock/issues/134). It has now been fixed by the developer.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to your own answer I was able to figure out what was causing same issue on my machine.

```
dfconf reset -f /org/gnome/
```

did the trick. However I did not want to lose all settings so I made backup using:

```
dfconf dump /org.gnome/ > backup_file
```

I started to narrow the problem and I found out that it was enough to reset `/org/gnome/shell/enabled-extensions`.

I am using a few extensions and I found out that the one that was causing all this mess is *Workspaces to Dock*.
All that was enough to disable this extension.

Comment: Oh wow, I use Workspaces to Dock too! Guess all I needed to do was to disable that extension as well. Anyway, thanks for taking the time to narrow it down to that. Hopefully it'll save someone else from all the headache