# How is Ubuntu 18.04 available already? (Lubuntu)

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu, 18.04

So, I have Lubuntu 17.10. Today I ran the update manager command and it says that Ubuntu 18.04 in available. Isn't the release date on the 26th? Is it the beta version? Is it a bug or something? Should I upgrade?

Comment: The easy way is to wait until Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is released. Several bugs are squashed now, and we might squash more bugs within the next few days. But you are welcome to participate in the testing,  [Ubuntu Development version / How to participate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate)

Comment: There have been bugs where the update process prematurely upgrades user to a future version before release date. In your case it happened on April 24th.

Answer (score 1):

According to [official site](https://lubuntu.net/downloads/) Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is available [since 2018-04-26](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/).

So you can try to start upgrade as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Today, my system had upgraded to 18.04. by usual command line (sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade)