# Can't update from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, update-manager

I have been trying to update my PC to Ubuntu 17.04. Apparently I can't. I have issues with these two.

```
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fonts-takao/fonts-takao-pgothic_00303.01-2ubuntu1_all.deb Hash Sum mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gdb/gdb_8.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb Hash Sum mismatch.
```

I have tried answers from [Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error)

I tried downloading several times everytime the update comes to like 1930/1931 downloaded and fails here.

I don’t know what is the issue. My PC previously stuck at a purple screen and I selected advanced options in GRUB and selected an old version of Ubuntu recovery from there.

Comment: I suggest that you wait until the first point release, 18.04.1 LTS, available in the end of July or beginning of August (unless you want to help debugging the new LTS release and the upgrade script). At that time you will find the option to upgrade from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS. Before that time several bugs will be squashed (in 18.04 LTS itself and in the upgrading tool). See also this link, [Ubuntu Development version / How to participate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate)

Comment: ***Reviewers / Close Voters***: This is not an EOL Release-specific question, and therefore is not off-topic: OP has 16.04 and is trying to upgrade it ot a newer release (but can't because 17.04 is EOL and 18.04.1 is not yet available so the 16.04 -> 18.04 upgrade path is not yet available).

Comment: can i just know what to do if i get error like failed to fetch.I entered the url in browser and immediately downloaded a .deb so whats the matter with software manager

Comment: Upgrading to a another release is always risky, so you should **backup** everything, that you cannot afford to lose before trying. It is a good idea to make a full backup of the current system (in your case Ubuntu16.04 LTS). After that you can take risks and upgrade, even if the upgrade system is not quite mature yet.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 17.04 is EOL.

Normally it is only allowed to upgrade to next version (16.10 which is also EOL) or next LTS version, 18.04.

So, upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 is the only supported option now.

Comment: When i check for updates in software packager i dont see 18.04 i.e when i selected lts then i dont see it there.When i selected for any version in the bottom area its showing me 17.04 as available.I think the software manager is broke.

Comment: @ThakurKarthik In update-manager's settings you can choose if you want to update to any new version or LTS only. Try to set it to LTS Only.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest LTS.  You can use the "-d" argument to upgrade to the latest supported release, which currently the latest **development release**.

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

You can avoid errors and conflicts by cleaning taking your repository library back to the defaults and running these commands:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt full-upgrade
```

This is the default source.list for Ubuntu 16.04:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

To avoid conflicts when trying to upgrade, backup your current `/etc/apt/sources.list` and use the default one.  After you have completed your upgrade, you can then migrate your custom repository listings back.

The release upgrade process usually automatically disables possible conflicting entries.  But it doesn't always work.

Comment: don't you need the `sudo`?