# How to update to the 18.10 beta?

Tags: upgrade, beta

I found CD images for the 18.10 beta, but I'm wondering if there is a way to upgrade OTA. I have the bionic-proposed box checked, but there is still nothing.

Comment: Questions related to any version prior to final release is off topic here.

Comment: This is about upgrading 18.04. Border case off topic I would say. But there IS an answer so I took the liberty to answer it. We do need beta testers, don't we?

Comment: 18.10 is Cosmic, not Bionic. Enabling the bionic-proposed repositories will do something other than you intended. Undo that.

Comment: See also the following link, [Ubuntu Development version / How to participate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate)

Answer (score 14):

Pre-requisites:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```

Those will make sure your current system is up to date.

Edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and set `Prompt=normal` to avoid the "No new release found message."

This will start the upgrade:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

### Big fat warnings:

- Please do not do this on a production server. 18.10 is not ready for general usage and breaking your system is more likely than having a working system. Every new update might break something.
- If you have personal data do make a backup every day and save them all. At some point you might need to re-install as every update could break your boot procedure. Knowing a little not more then average about the inner workings of Ubuntu so the base system, Linux, systemd, the boot process would be good to have.
- Biggest problem probably will be 3rd party drivers. I would remove them and stick to the open source versions when upgrading and re-enable them when there is a working newer system.