# Missing indicator/tray icons (Steam, Chrome, Dropbox, etc)

Tags: indicator, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

On my installations of Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10 all the indicator icons from Chrome, Dropbox, Ulauncher, InSync and Steam are missing.
These are the indicator currently installed:
[image]

And these are the Gnome extensions installed:
[image]

Looking Glass shows no error for the `gnome-shell-extension-appindicator`:
[image]

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 is not yet released and therefore off-topic at AskUbuntu. See the following link, if you want to participate in the development and testing, [Ubuntu Development version / How to participate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate)

Comment: I find out the problem and I discovered that the same thing can happen also on Ubuntu 18.04. I'm going to post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was having Unity and its indicators installed. After removing completely Unity and all its indicators the icons are back:

[image]

This is the list of the package with "indicator" in the name you should have installed:

```
$ apt list --installed | grep indicator    

gnome-shell-extension-appindicator/cosmic,cosmic,now 22-1 all [installed]
libappindicator1/cosmic,now 12.10.1+18.04.20180322.1-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libappindicator3-1/cosmic,now 12.10.1+18.04.20180322.1-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libindicator3-7/cosmic,now 16.10.0+18.04.20180321.1-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libindicator7/cosmic,now 16.10.0+18.04.20180321.1-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Comment: Great! Removing Unity fixed it for me.

Comment: Nice, but this really isn't a solution to the problem.  Most people did not use any Unity features - certainly not unity-tweak - when installing 18.10, and so there is nothing to remove.  The indicators are still missing for me and for many others.

Comment: This fixes the issue where you don't get any app indicator at all. Unfortunately some apps still don't show the icon, like Chrome in my case.