# No tray icons for OBS and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, indicator, gnome-shell, system-tray, obs-studio

I am currently running Ubuntu 19.04 (Gnome 3.32) and experience that some programs (e.g. Chrome and OBS) don't show a tray icon.
Rambox or Skype e.g. work perfectly.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: You might neec https://github.com/ubuntu/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator  if you are using gnome

Comment: It's installed but doesn't bring them up sadly.

Comment: Then you might want to check https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079510/missing-indicator-tray-icons-steam-chrome-dropbox-etc

Comment: I followed that, but didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, but i found out that in newest version of OBS they made tray indicators to be OFF by default. 
So i did it myself.
It's in a **File-Setting-System Tray.**
(I use Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS)