# How can I repair the small bugs in my Ubuntu version?

Tags: dual-boot, boot-repair, error-handling

I made a mistake by upgrading all the way from ubuntu 16.04 to the 19.04 developement version because I wanted to see what it was like. 18.10 installed perfectly, but when I upgraded to 19.04 I was notified that there were some glitches during the install. I had to create my own downloads folder and all downloads still go to Home, and I recently got a System Problem Detected pop up.

I cleared the crash reports, but I got a lot of crashes during 16.04 which made me sick. I am quite OCD about software I spend a lot of time with and knowing there might be multiple bugs in my 19.04 installation makes me quite uncomfortable.

I tried sudo touch /forcefsck which did nothing when I rebooted my system and I created a USB Ubuntu 18.10 Boot Flashdrive and ran every version of fsck and e2fsck I could think of or find online. Every single one of them failed and did nothing. After every sudo fsck command (even using -f), I ran echo $? and it always returned 0 saying no action taken.

How can I successfully do a 'deep clean' of 19.04 to remove as many potential errors in my system as possible? If you're unable to help, I am heavily considering doing a complete reformat of my Ubuntu OS to version 18.10. I am dreading this because of all the software I would need to reinstall, but it's very preferable to thinking I'm stuck living with multiple bugs.

I have a dual boot on my laptop with windows 7 as my second OS.

Comment: I think the best thing you can do is: 1. Backup all personal files to another drive; 2. Make a **fresh installation** of 18.04.1 LTS if you want a smooth ride, or if you want more adventures, 18.10 or if you want to participate in development and testing, the not yet released version, which will soon become 19.04. See also this link: [Ubuntu Development version / How to participate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate)