# My ubuntu 20.04 lokks different than others

Tags: upgrade, 20.04

I can't find the menu panel which was previously available on bottom left. This looks completely different from the one saw in pictures.

[screenshot-desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SePk0.jpg)

Comment: Which Ubuntu version number and flavour name did you use previously?

Comment: I was using 18.04. Now I have upgraded to 20.04. I am unable to find dock panel and appearance setting.

Comment: The tool for upgrading from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS is still in the developing phase. It will not be officially supported until the first point release, 20.04.1 LTS late in July. So you may experience glitches, when you use it now. See also [this link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes) and [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate).