# Can't upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 LTS -> Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, updates, update-manager

Upgrade to version 20 does not complete. Goes to Read Status Information and then stops. I tried to update both through the terminal and through update-manager - the result does not change (

```
develop@dev-pc:~$ sudo su
root@dev-pc:/home/develop# sudo /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk:30: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
WARNING:root:timeout reached, exiting
root@dev-pc:/home/develop# nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
root@dev-pc:/home/develop# do-release-upgrade -d
Проверка наличия нового релиза Ubuntu
Получено:1 Подпись утилиты обновления [1 554 B]                                                     
Получено:2 Утилита обновления [1 333 kB]                                                            
Получено 1 334 kБ за 0с (0 Б/c)                                                                     
аутентифицировать 'focal.tar.gz' вместо 'focal.tar.gz.gpg' 
извлечение 'focal.tar.gz'

Чтение временных файлов

Проверка менеджера пакетов
Чтение списков пакетов... Выполнено
Построение дерева зависимостей        
Чтение информации о состоянии... Выполнено
В кэше http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                       
В кэше http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease                            
В кэше http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                            
В кэше https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                                               
Получено:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88,7 kB]                      
В кэше https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                 
Получено:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]                     
Получено 177 kБ за 0с (0 Б/c)                                                                       
Чтение списков пакетов... Выполнено       
Построение дерева зависимостей             
Чтение информации о состоянии... Выполнено

Восстановление первоначального состояния системы

Прерывание
Чтение списков пакетов... Выполнено       
Построение дерева зависимостей             
Чтение информации о состоянии... Выполнено
```

Comment: At first you have to install all upgrades for the bionic system by running `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` then run `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` again.

Comment: Browse to this link: [If you want to help develop and debug the latest and greatest Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate/1018060#1018060) and scroll down to **If you want a smooth ride**. I think the do-release-upgrade scripts to 20.04.1 LTS will be debugged and officially published within a few days (maybe tomorrow,Thursday).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely uninstalled SNAP and installed it. After that, everything immediately worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Trying changing the update server. Use google to search all available update servers and edit the URL in the system using vim or nano.

Follow this link, it might help you.....
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-select-the-fastest-apt-mirror-on-ubuntu-linux

Edit: Sometimes Ubuntu 20.04 may be in development version in your region, if you want the stable version change your mirror server.

Comment: the update manager connects to the server successfully, the download is successful. The installation script breaks immediately after loading the data