# virtualbox no longer starts after upgrade from ubuntu 22.10 to 23.04

Tags: kubuntu, virtualbox, freeze, 23.04

virtualbox 6.1.38 worked flawlessly under Kubuntu 22.10. The virtual machine (Windows 10 pro) ran without problems!
Then I was offered the upgrade to Kubuntu 23.04, which I then also carried out. Third party software had to be post-installed.
But unfortunately Oracle Virtualbox was automatically updated to version 7.0.6 r155176! **And does not run!!!!!**
When I start the virtual machine (Windows 10 pro), the VirtualBox boot screen is displayed, which then freezes and the virtual machine can only be terminated hard.
Installing the missing extension pack (guest extension) does not produce any other results.
Questions:

1. how do I get Virtuelbox 7.0.6 r155176 to work?
2. how do I switch to the old VirtuelBox version 6.1.38?
3. does an update from VirtuelBox 7.0.6 to 7.0_7.0.8 "virtualbox-7.0_7.0.8-156879~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64" work?
4. how do I delete a VirtuelBox installation completely without deleting the configuration and the installation drive of the virtual machine?
5. how do I customize the kernel modules?
   Greetings Frank

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: When a version is new, some application programs are not yet upgraded. If you want a smooth ride, you should run versions with long time support, LTS. Those versions are released in April even years, so the most recent version now is 22.04 LTS, and there is a second point release iso file, 22.04.2 LTS. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate-or-how-to-get-a-smooth-ride?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C49.6762).

Comment: Do basic troubleshooting before going down the rabbit-hole of changing anything. Changing random things might make it worse. Check your logs. Check `top`' and  `free` during a freeze. Look for reproducibility. Copy/backup the virtual hard drive. Try to open the virtual hard drive using a LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment. Try LiveUSBs for both 22.10 and 23.04.

Comment: Try this: https://www.reddit.com/r/virtualbox/comments/yh4dad/windows_11_guest_os_keeps_freezingcrashing/
It looks like the VirtualBox upgrade changed the 3D acceleration setting for me and the above change fixed it.

Comment: Try to downgrade VirtualBox Guest Additions software (for your Windows virtual machine)  to the latest 6.x... Version 7.x of Guest Additions software is known to have these freeze problems currently.