# Upgrade to 23.04 with big problems

Tags: upgrade, 23.04

At the release day I have done my upgrade from Ubuntu 220.10 to 23.04. Many times already I have done these updates but never it has heavily impacted my graphical system: Mouse and keyboard are not working properly anymore, Klick-Menues are not showing up. Instruments in GIMP are not or wrong working, File-Manager is working confused (instead scrolling Files are mangnifying or minimizing. I am more or less blocked to work with my desktop.
On my laptop I have upgraded too but there I have no problems.
What has happed? What can I do? The photo shows what happens during boot. I didn't have that before with 22.10
[image]

---

My hardware is an Acer Aspire X3990, Mouse and Keyboard are Logitech. Up to now I never had such problema after upgrading and I am with Ubuntu since 20 years and more.

Comment: I am feeling your pain....do you get a desktop?

Comment: Meanwhile it seems that booting ubuntu xorg makes the problem a bit easier. But it is not yet solved. Still not everything is working as usual under Nautilus or GIMP. In Nautilus scrolling with the muse wheel sometimes jumps to magnifying by down scrolling and minimizing by up scrolling. Some of the tools of GIMP are not working and giving strange messages instead.

Comment: As beside of the compassion note of gfmore there is not respond let me ask: could it be a solution to make a complete new installation of Ubuntu 23.04? I think about that because maybe there has happened something wrong during the process of upgrading.

Comment: Yes, there are many more obstacles when release-upgrading compared to backing up the personal data and making a fresh installation. I think the reason is that there are many settings for the old version's set of programs that may cause confusion after the release-upgrade. - The first step is to boot into the USB drive with the new version of Ubuntu and run it live 'testing' how it works before you decide if want to install it.

Comment: Generally I suggest to **stay with the Ubuntu versions with long time support if you want a smooth ride**. Such versions are released in April even years. The current one is 22.04.x LTS. Only if your hardware is too new for the LTS version there is reason to use a short-life version in order to get the newest possible version. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate-or-how-to-get-a-smooth-ride/1018060?r=SearchResults&s=6%7C5.6196#1018060) with more details.

Comment: @sudodus, yes a good lesson learnt. When I did try to boot with a rufus created usb from 23.04 iso the machine failed to boot even. I have reverted back to 22.10, but am now looking at :shhhh ... Fedora :(

Comment: It's OK as long as you stay with Linux :-P

Comment: By the way, what computer is it? If you specify the brand name of the computer itself and of the graphics chip/card, it may be possible to suggest a solution with Ubuntu.

Comment: This should be a part of your question, not posted as an answer since it is not an answer.

Comment: You are describing multiple widespread problems with no apparent cause that are unlikely to be related. Your choices are to try to search down the cause of each problem and fix each problem, or you can reinstall the OS. How long will it take you to find/fix everything? Unknown. Will it solve everything or crew new problems? Unknown. How long to reinstall the OS? An hour or so, tops. Will it solve everything? Yes.... I suggest you reinstall the OS. I also suggest you use Ubuntu 22.04 and only run an interim/experimental release if you want to help test new software.

Comment: The computer is a second hand HP Proliant Microserver Gen8 - £300 and 12TB of disks - and v quiet. Yes and after a go with Fedora 38 which wouldn't work the way it needed to (dual boot) I've managed to reload Ubuntu 22.04 - took more than an hour ;)