# USB CD/DVD not detected by 23.04

Tags: usb, kernel, raspberrypi, dvd, 23.04

Completed a fresh install of 23.04 desktop on Raspberry Pi 4. All good until I connected my external CD/DVD drive, which was pnp on 22.04 and 22.10. No joy on the lobster. Neither Disks utility nor lshw indicate its presence. A HW probe indicated this is a known issue with the current Linux kernel and USB 3.0 controller, but gave no solution or workaround. Suggestions? I'm a semi-linux literate retiree using the Pi as a PC and AV media center.

Comment: Stay with the Ubuntu versions with long time support if you want a smooth ride. Such versions are released in April even years. The current one is 22.04.x LTS. Only if your hardware is too new for the LTS version there is reason to use a short-life version in order to get the newest possible version. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate-or-how-to-get-a-smooth-ride/1018060?r=SearchResults&s=6%7C5.6196#1018060) with more details.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't ask about 22.04.

Comment: Sorry, but I had no immediate solution, so I suggested a workaround. When your problem is reported as a bug at Launchpad, the developers can start analyzing the cause and, let us hope, squash the bug. But it may take time, maybe months.