# Keyboard layout not working on Wayland

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, wayland

I have a Hungarian keyboard layout, and I would like to have it working on Ubuntu 23.04 (or 23.10 recently). If i log into Ubuntu Xorg everything works perfectly, however in normal (I guess that is wayland) very strange things happen.

I have Hungarian and English layout added. I have "Use the same source on all windows" enabled. Now If I log into Ubuntu (without xorg) I have the Hungarian layout on the Application menu search bar (top left corner on desktop) and in default terminal but English US on every other window like firefox, GUAKE terminal etc. If I switch to English and back to Hungarian nothing happens. If I go into the settings, remove Hungarian and add it again, it suddenly works.

I would like to avoid adding and removing a language on each startup by hand and I would like to use wayland for other reasons.

It was present in 23.04, and yesterday I upgraded to 23.10 hoping it would go away, but it is still present.

Any solution for this problem?

Comment: Do you need some feature(s) present in 23.04 and 23.10, that are not available in the newest version with long time support, 22.04.x LTS? Otherwise I would suggest that you save (backup) your personal data and install Ubuntu 22.04.x LTS because it has long time support *and* it is better debugged and polished. See also [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate-or-how-to-get-a-smooth-ride) and the paragraph about 'smooth ride'.

Comment: @sudodus I do not have anything that ties me to 23.*, just wanted to use Ubuntu as a 'rolling' distro with each new update.

Comment: Which method do you use when attempting to switch keyboard layout?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson The manual switcher applet at the top right of the screen